# Recursively find and replace string in text files

Tags: python

I want to recursively search through a directory with subdirectories of text files and replace every occurrence of `{$replace}` within the files with the contents of a multi line string. How can this be achieved with Python?

So far all I have is the recursive code using `os.walk` to get a list of files that are required to be changed.

```
import os
import sys
fileList = []
rootdir = "C:\\test"
for root, subFolders, files in os.walk(rootdir):
  if subFolders != ".svn":
    for file in files:
      fileParts = file.split('.')
      if len(fileParts) > 1:
        if fileParts[1] == "php":
          fileList.append(os.path.join(root,file))
      
      
print fileList
```

Comment: Why do you need to use Python for this?  A combination of `find` and `sed` would do the job more elegantly, in my opinion.  http://developmentality.wordpress.com/2010/09/07/unix-tip-3-introduction-to-find-grep-sed/ Basically, `find . -type f -exec sed -i '.bk' 's/search regexp/replacement string/g' {} \;` (Haven't tested but I think that's the correct syntax)

Comment: @I82Much - but your solution would require learning sed. If OP already knows basic Python, and is not obsessed learning new tool (prefers mastering existing ones), solving the task in Python makes more sense.

Comment: @I82Much: `c:\test` might be one reason (Windows). `find /c/test -type d -path \*/.svn -prune -o -type f -name \*.php -exec sed -i 's/{\$replace}/multiline\nstring/g' {} +`  shell command is close to [this Python code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885751/4279)

Comment: @I82Much - what is or what for '.bk' ?; sed -i (inplace) 's/old/new/g' (substitution)

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Check out [os.walk](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk):

```
import os
replacement = """some
multi-line string"""
for dname, dirs, files in os.walk("some_dir"):
    for fname in files:
        fpath = os.path.join(dname, fname)
        with open(fpath) as f:
            s = f.read()
        s = s.replace("{$replace}", replacement)
        with open(fpath, "w") as f:
            f.write(s)
```

The above solution has flaws, such as the fact that it opens literally every file it finds, or the fact that each file is read entirely into memory (which would be bad if you had a 1GB text file), but it should be a good starting point.

You also may want to look into the [re module](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html) if you want to do a more complex find/replace than looking for a specific string.

Comment: It should be line `s = "" ` before line `with open`...

Comment: @Alex how so? Variables are function-scoped, not block scoped, so this code should be fine.

Answer (score 73):

os.walk is great. However, it looks like you need to filer file types (which I would suggest if you are going to walk some directory). To do this, you should add `import fnmatch`.

```
import os, fnmatch
def findReplace(directory, find, replace, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
```

This allows you to do something like:

```
findReplace("some_dir", "find this", "replace with this", "*.txt")
```

Comment: to avoid loading the whole file in memory, you could use [`fileinput` module](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25885751/4279)

Answer (score 15):

For those using **Python 3.5+** you can now use a [glob](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html) recursively with the use of `**` and the `recursive` flag.

Here's an example replacing `hello` with `world` for all `.txt` files:

```
for filepath in glob.iglob('./**/*.txt', recursive=True):
    with open(filepath) as file:
        s = file.read()
    s = s.replace('hello', 'world')
    with open(filepath, "w") as file:
        file.write(s)
```

Comment: For windows might end up with error `'UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 676628: character maps to'` This is encoding error. Refer this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233174/452708

Comment: Some users might have to **import glob** first.

Answer (score 7):

To avoid recursing into `.svn` directories, [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk) allows you to change the `dirs` list inplace. To simplify the text replacement in a file without requiring to read the whole file in memory, you could use [`fileinput` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html). And to filter filenames using a file pattern, you could use [`fnmatch` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fnmatch.html#fnmatch.filter) as [suggested by @David Sulpy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15629678/4279):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from __future__ import print_function
import fnmatch
import os
from fileinput import FileInput

def find_replace(topdir, file_pattern, text, replacement):
    for dirpath, dirs, files in os.walk(topdir, topdown=True):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d != '.svn'] # skip .svn dirs
        files = [os.path.join(dirpath, filename)
                 for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, file_pattern)]
        for line in FileInput(files, inplace=True):
            print(line.replace(text, replacement), end='')

find_replace(r"C:\test", "*.php", '{$replace}', "multiline\nreplacement")
```

Answer (score 5):

This is an old question but I figured I'd provide an updated and simpler answer using current libraries in python3.8.

```
from pathlib import Path
import re

rootdir = Path("C:\\test")
pattern = r'REGEX for the text you want to replace'
replace = r'REGEX for what to replace it with'

for file in [ f for f in rootdir.glob("**.php") ]: #modify glob pattern as needed
  file_contents = file.read_text()
  new_file_contents = re.sub(f"{pattern}", f"{replace}", file_contents)
  file.write_text(new_file_contents)
```

Comment: `rootdir.rglob` to get all subfolders too

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by others, the way to go is glob. However, use binary mode to prevent changing line endings when you find/replace.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3

replacements = [
# find, replace
(b'#include <Common/LogLevelInfo.h>', b'#include <Common/LogLevelErr.h>'),
(b'#include <Common/LogLevelDbg.h>', b'#include <Common/LogLevelErr.h>'),
(b'#include <Common/LogLevelErr.h>', b'#include <Common/LogLevelNone.h>'),
]
# path to files. here all cpp files in the current working directory
globpath = './**/*.cpp'

import glob
for filepath in glob.iglob(globpath, recursive=True):
    with open(filepath, 'rb') as file:
        s = file.read()
    for f, r in replacements:
        s = s.replace(f, r)
    with open(filepath, "wb") as file:
        file.write(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
pip3 install manip
```

This lets you use a decorator to create something like:

```
@manip(at='.php$', recursive=True) # to apply to subfolders
def replace_on_php(text, find, replacement):
    return text.replace(find, replacement)
```

Now in your prompt you should be able to call

```
replace_on_php('explode', 'myCustomExplode', path='./myPhPFiles', modify=True)
```

and this should make the function apply itself on the entire folder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code (which I think is the same as the above but I'm including it just in case there's something subtly different about it):

```
import os, fnmatch, sys
def findReplace(directory, find, replace, filePattern):
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):         
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
```

it runs without error. 
BUT, the file, in `z:\test` is unchanged.
I've put in print statements, like `print("got here")` but they don't print out either.

Answer (score 0):

Sulpy's answer is good but incomplete. The user would be likely to want to input the parameters through an entry widget, so we might have something more like this (also incomplete, but left as an exercise):

```
import os, fnmatch
from Tkinter import *
fields = 'Folder', 'Search', 'Replace', 'FilePattern'

def fetch(entvals):
#    print entvals
#    print ents
    entItems = entvals.items()
    for entItem in entItems:
        field = entItem[0]
        text  = entItem[1].get()
        print('%s: "%s"' % (field, text))

def findReplace(entvals):
#    print ents
    directory = entvals.get("Folder").get()
    find = entvals.get("Search").get()
    replace = entvals.get("Replace").get()
    filePattern = entvals.get("FilePattern").get()
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, filePattern):
#            print filename
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            print filepath  # Can be commented out --  used for confirmation
            with open(filepath) as f:
                s = f.read()
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)

def makeform(root, fields):
    entvals = {}
    for field in fields:
        row = Frame(root)
        lab = Label(row, width=17, text=field+": ", anchor='w')
        ent = Entry(row)
        row.pack(side=TOP, fill=X, padx=5, pady=5)
        lab.pack(side=LEFT)
        ent.pack(side=RIGHT, expand=YES, fill=X)
        entvals[field] = ent
#        print ent
    return entvals

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Recursive S&R")
    ents = makeform(root, fields)
#    print ents
    root.bind('<Return>', (lambda event, e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1 = Button(root, text='Show', command=(lambda e=ents: fetch(e)))
    b1.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b2 = Button(root, text='Execute', command=(lambda e=ents: findReplace(e)))
    b2.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    b3 = Button(root, text='Quit', command=root.quit)
    b3.pack(side=LEFT, padx=5, pady=5)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: "The user would be likely to want to input the parameters through an entry widget" seems pretty presumptuous and unrelated to the question. "The user" might be just as likely inputting the parameters through a React front end to a Django backend, but there's no sense in adding all of that code as an answer any more than any other user interface.

Answer (score -1):

How about just using:

```
clean = ''.join([e for e in text if e != 'string'])
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to have anything to do with the question.