# GithHub pages - not returning to index html

Tags: python-3.x, flask, github-pages

I published my application created in Flask and Python3 via GitHub pages but it seems that when I want to click `back` on my page it returns to `https://jurestabuc.github.io/` instead of the root of the app which is at `https://jurestabuc.github.io/news-terror-app/build/index.html`.

Somebody can tell me what I've been doing wrong?

This is the detail page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <title>Terror</title>
</head>
<body>
  <header>
    <h1>In {{ object.iyear }}, {{ object.nkill }} people died in attacks in {{ object.city }}, {{ object.country_txt }}. The attack was carried out by {{ object.gname }}.</h1>
  </header>
  <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:300px;"></div>
  <p><a href="/">&laquo; Back</a></p>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = L.map("map").setView([{{ object.latitude }}, {{ object.longitude }}], 16);
    var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a>.'
    });
    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    var marker = L.marker([{{ object.latitude }}, {{ object.longitude }}]).addTo(map);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Index page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='style.css') }}" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.css" />
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.0.3/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
  <title>Terror</title>
</head>
<body>
  <!-- <nav>
    <a href="">
      <img src="">
    </a>
  </nav> -->
  <header>
    <h1>50 worst acts of terrorism in Western Europe</h1>
    <div class="byline">
      By <a href="https://twitter.com/JureStabuc">Jure Stabuc</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:400px;"></div>
  <table border=1 cellpadding=7>
    <tr>
      <th>City</th>
      <th>Country</th>
      <th>Year</th>
      <th>Type of attack</th>
      <th>Target</th>
      <th>Number of dead</th>
      <th>Terrorist organisation</th>
      <!-- <th>Motive</th> -->
      <!-- <th>Weapons</th> -->
    </tr>
    {% for obj in object_list %}
    <tr>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.city }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.country_txt}}</a></td>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.iyear }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.attacktype1_txt}}</a></td>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.target1 }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.nkill }}</a></td>
      <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.gname }}</a></td>
      <!-- <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.motive }}</a></td> -->
      <!-- <td><a href="{{ obj.id }}/">{{ obj.weapdetail}}</a></td> -->
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
  </table>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var map = L.map("map").setView([50.0000, 20.0000], 4);
    var osmLayer = new L.TileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 18,
        attribution: 'Data, imagery and map information provided by <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/" target="_blank">OpenStreetMap</a>.'
    });
    map.addLayer(osmLayer);
    var data = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {% for obj in object_list %}
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {
            "city": "{{ obj.city }}",
            "id": "{{ obj.id }}"
          },
          "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [{{ obj.longitude }}, {{ obj.latitude }}]
          }
        }{% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
      ]
    };
    var dataLayer = L.geoJson(data, {
      onEachFeature: function(feature, layer) {
        layer.bindPopup(
          "<a href = '" + feature.properties.id + "/'>" + feature.properties.city + "</a>"
        );
      }
    });
    map.addLayer(dataLayer);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

app.py:

```
import csv
from flask import Flask
from flask import abort
from flask import render_template
app = Flask(__name__)

def get_csv():
    csv_path ="./static/top50weu.csv"
    #adding encoding because of issues with it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c
    csv_file = open(csv_path, "r", encoding="latin-1")
    #parsed and returned as a list of dictionaries
    csv_obj = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    csv_list = list(csv_obj)
    return csv_list

@app.route("/")
def index():
    template ="index.html"
    object_list = get_csv()
    return render_template(template, object_list=object_list)

@app.route("/<row_id>/")
def detail(row_id):
    template = "detail.html"
    object_list = get_csv()
    for row in object_list:
        if row["id"] == row_id:
            return render_template(template, object=row)
    abort(404)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    #Fire up the Flask test server
    app.run(debug=True, use_reloader=True)
```

freeze.py:

```
from flask_frozen import Freezer
from app import app, get_csv
freezer = Freezer(app)
app.config['FREEZER_RELATIVE_URLS'] = True


@freezer.register_generator
def detail():
    for row in get_csv():
        yield {"row_id": row["id"]}

if __name__ == '__main__':
    freezer.freeze()
```

Locally everything is ok. Example is available at: [app](https://jurestabuc.github.io/news-terror-app/build/index.html) Thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out instead of `<a href="/">&laquo; Back</a>` I used `<a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">&laquo; Back</a>` and is working correctly.