# UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u2019' in position 35: ordinal not in range(128)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, urllib

When I parsed a urllib, I got a UnicodeEncodeError. Follows are my codes.

```
import urllib.request, urllib.parse, urllib.error   
def read_test():
    quotes = open("C:\\movie_quotes.txt")
    contents_of_file = quotes.read()
    print(contents_of_file)
    quotes.close()
    check_profanity(contents_of_file)

def check_profanity(text_to_check):
    connection = urllib.request.urlopen("http://www.wdylike.appspot.com/?q="+text_to_check)
   output = connection.read()
   print(output)
   connection.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    read_test()
```

Comment: Which line generates the error? And which version of Python?

Comment: 7 and 10 lines.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xa0' in position 20: ordinal not in range(128)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9942594/unicodeencodeerror-ascii-codec-cant-encode-character-u-xa0-in-position-20)

Comment: I read that, but I can not understand a lot. Would you like to type correct codes for me?

Comment: Consider using `codecs.open`.  See http://stackoverflow.com/a/12468274/2904896

Comment: You should include the stack trace in your post, and you need to tell us your Python version, as already requested by Mark. Most probably the problem is that you're creating a URL with an arbitrary string. You need to [urlencode](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) that first.