# How to input html in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to input html document into my python.

I get this error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'cp950' codec can't decode byte 0xbb in position
>   362: illegal multibyte sequence

when using this code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xxx.html))  
print(soup)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Answer (score 0):

you are facing a encode/decode problem.
try this:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('xxx.html', encoding='your xxx.html file encoding'))
```

you can find 'your xxx.html encoding' by searching 'charset' in the file.
then, you will get something like `charset=utf-8` or other `charset=xxx`
behind '=', 'utf-8' or 'xxx', is your xxx.html encoding