# python 3.6 decoding text from server

Tags: python, file, text, decode

I am running a python code on server (python 3.6). It tries to read a csv file which has this structure:

```
I'll    510 676 1   Speaker2
come back   727 878 3   Speaker2
and wake you    930 1196    3   Speaker2
sp  1196    1242    99  Speaker2
in twenty   1109    1401    3   Speaker2
to  1544    1631    1   Speaker2
give you    1631    1952    3   Speaker2
```

This piece of code:

```
with open(csvfile, 'r') as f:
   lines = f.readlines()
```

returns this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode bytes in position 15-16: invalid continuation byte
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c) but it didn't work

Comment: have you read error mesage? have you manually checked what it points to?

Comment: seeing the file would be usefule

Comment: Did you try `csvfile = unicode(csvfile, errors='ignore')`, before the `with open` ?

Comment: I did. and I got: NameError: name 'unicode' is not defined [which I think its a python 3.6 problem]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that it wasn't a real CSV. When I saved as CSV again, it worked!