# ‘Utf-8’code can not decode byte 0xcd in position 0

Tags: pandas

I am a  newbie to python and data analysis, when I try to read .csv files by pandas, I got the information as below.

> ‘Utf-8’ code can’t decode byte 0xcd in position 0: invalid
>   continuation byte.

This is not the first time I got this problem, unfortunately I forgot how to solve it. Could someone help me?

my code:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(‘C:/Users/36373748/files/zllr.csv’)
```

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone! I tried the pd.read_csv commend with encoding =‘gbk’, and it finally worked!