# Python 3: utf-8 opening file from desktop

Tags: python-3.x

I get the error 'utf-8'.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xca in position 5: invalid continuation byte*
```

I don't know why this happens. I am trying this:

```
path = "/Users/Lieve/Desktop/"
contents = open(path+"100_names.txt")
lines = contents.readlines()
```

Comment: This might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c Try to look for answers before posting a question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)