# Importing csv using pd.read_csv - invalid start byte error

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to import a csv file using:

```
data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv")
```

I get the following error: `"UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 2: invalid start byte".`

The answer in this question: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)
might work, but I am not sure how to implement it (I can't comment on the answer because I don't have enough reputation yet).

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: The issue seems to be linked to the fact that I have a degree symbol. It would be fine for me if during import this issue is just skipped.

Comment: You'll have to post a link to your raw data

Comment: Thanks for the reply @EdChum, managed to figure out a work around which was to skip the row which had the offending symbol: data = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", skiprows=[1])

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you face an encoding error due to encoding on your file not being the default as mentioned by the `pd.read_csv()` docs , you can find the encoding of the file by first installing [`chardet`](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html) followed by the below code:

```
import chardet    
rawdata = open('D:\\path\\file.csv', 'rb').read()
result = chardet.detect(rawdata)
charenc = result['encoding']
print(charenc)
```

This will give you the encoding of the file.

Once you have the encoding, you can read as :

```
pd.read_csv('D:\\path\\file.csv',encoding = 'encoding you found')
```

or

```
pd.read_csv(r'D:\path\file.csv',encoding = 'encoding you found')
```

You will get the list of all encoding [here](https://docs.python.org/2.4/lib/standard-encodings.html)

Hope you find this useful.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Really enjoying this solution, it has worked perfectly, and by placing charenc into the read statement it's done automatically: pd.read_csv('D:\\path\\file.csv',encoding = charenc)

Comment: Great solution, much better than hard coding a encoding, while often you don't know this in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I solved mine by simply going back to the excel sheet and saving using the format 'CSV UTF-8'

Answer (score -1):

You can use the encoding argument of the pandas function read_csv.

It can look something like that if it really need to be encode in utf-8.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("filename.csv", encoding = 'utf_8')
```