# Python Pandas writer.save() encoding error - UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe and am trying to export this to excel file using pandas to_excel function.

I have written the code as below :

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path, engine='xlsxwriter')
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', index=False, encoding='utf-8')
writer.save()
```

**Error :**
`UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 23: ordinal` not in range(128)

I have tried the below options and didn't get output.

1)

```
import sys  
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('utf8')
```

2)

```
def changeencode(data):
cols = data.columns
for col in cols:
if data[col].dtype == 'O':
    data[col] = data[col].str.decode('utf-8').str.encode('ascii', 'ignore')
return data
```

Does anyone know any other solutions ?

Comment: does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133455/importing-csv-using-pd-read-csv-invalid-start-byte-error/54134734#54134734) help?

Comment: @anky_91 how to do this for writing to an excel file (to_excel)?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default encoding to be `Cp1252` and then try. That would work.

```
import sys
reload(sys)  
sys.setdefaultencoding('Cp1252')
```

Comment: Still facing error : 'UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 23: character maps to <undefined>' . When i try to see  sys.getdefaultencoding() i got 'ascii'