# Unable to read CSV file from C drive

Tags: python, pandas

Trying to read CSV file using pandas in Pycharm for a python project. Getting an error when i run the code
I tried all the past solutions like adding "r" or double slash or mentioning the encoding. It does not seem to work.

Using `read_csv` using pandas library.
Tried using double slash in the file path but it didn't work.

UPDATE
updated the code as below
Apparently, one of the issues with the CSV file was that there was no header in the file. Below worked just fine:

```
import pandas as pd
path = "c:/ML_Cricket/CSV/225171.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path,error_bad_lines=False,names=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11"])
print(df)
```

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("C:\ML_Cricket\CSV\221571.csv")

print(df.head())
```

I get this traceback:

```
C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\Scripts\python.exe C:/Users/abc/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "C:/Users/abc/.PyCharmCE2019.1/config/scratches/scratch.py", line 3, in <module>
   df = pd.read_csv("C:\ML_Cricket\CSV\221571.csv")
 File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
   return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
 File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 429, in _read
   parser = TextFileReader(filepath_or_buffer, **kwds)
 File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 895, in __init__
   self._make_engine(self.engine)
 File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1122, in _make_engine
   self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
 File "C:\Users\abc\PycharmProjects\untitled\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1853, in __init__
   self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 387, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
 File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 686, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
UnicodeEncodeError: 'mbcs' codec can't encode characters in position 0--1: invalid character
```

Comment: @hiroprotagonist editing the traceback as a quote has trashed the formatting. Why didn't you edit as code? :/

Comment: A guess: `df = pd.read_csv("C:\ML_Cricket\CSV\221571.csv", encoding='cp1252')`

Comment: Did not work :(

Comment: @roganjosh yes, that was a bad decision... tried to fix (but that also looks bad...) do you have a better way of formatting tracebacks here?

Comment: hmm. now anky_91 converted it back to quote...

Comment: You need to escape the backslashes: `"C:\\ML_Cricket\\CSV\\221571.csv"`

Comment: @hiroprotagonist I think that, once it goes into quotation format, it cannot be undone properly. Anecdotally, and as I experienced here, I never seem to be able to get it back into correct format. Or maybe it's the pasted format that cannot be converted into code format in the first place that makes people format as quotes. A properly-pasted traceback should be convertible into code format with no issues.

Comment: @AnoopMahajan check with [`chardet`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133455/importing-csv-using-pd-read-csv-invalid-start-byte-error/54134734#54134734) may be.. also escape the `\\` as rainer suggests

Comment: Tried the double backslash but it did not work

Comment: @roganjosh i took the source from the original edit to paste as code - i did not just undo my edit... now it looks good anyway. thanks for your advice!

Comment: "_It doesnt seem to work_" How? Are you getting the same error? A different error? Does the code run but with weird behaviour? Is there a memory leak? Is the OS blowing up? Please be specific. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this.

```
df = pd.read_csv("c:/ML_Cricket/CSV/221571.csv")
```

Comment: What is the difference between wat I am using and this? it doesnt work btw...

Comment: Its using forward slashes instead of back stashes