# Importing txt using pd.read_csv - invalid start byte error

Tags: python, pandas, txt

I am trying to read a txt file from a url:

```
df = pd.read_csv(url, sep = "@#$", header = None, engine = 'python')
```

But I get the following error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x9b in position 3706: invalid start byte
```

I tried the following based on solutions I found online:

```
error_bad_lines = False
encoding = 'utf_8'
encoding = 'utf_16'
```

I tried the answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54133455/importing-csv-using-pd-read-csv-invalid-start-byte-error)
. But I get the following error when I try that:

```
TypeError: Expected object of type bytes or bytearray, got: <class 'http.client.HTTPResponse'>
```

But nothing is working. Any other ideas?

Comment: Where did URL come from?  Are you running Windows?  0x9B is the right pointing angle bracket (">") in Windows CP1252, so it's not UTF-8 at all.

Comment: @TimRoberts I am using a Windows laptop but I am running the code on EC2 (Ubuntu) 
But there is a ">" in the file. I checked it now

Comment: Try out `encoding='cp1252'` as @TimRoberts suggested, and if you're still getting a error, please include all your code and the full traceback. We can't diagnose just from the exception line. See this post on [understanding the python traceback](https://realpython.com/python-traceback/).

Comment: If you want to cheat, you could just use an editor to replace that with a greater-than sign, but what you really need to do is read that in with `open('name',encoding='cp1252')`.