# UnicodeDecodeError 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 2893: invalid start byte

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, character-encoding

I'm trying to open a series of HTML files in order to get the text from the body of those files using BeautifulSoup. I have about 435 files that I wanted to run through but I keep getting this error.

I've tried converting the HTML files to text and opening the text files but I get the same error...

```
path = "./Bitcoin"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), "r") as fname:
        txt = fname.read()
```

I want to get the source code of the HTML file so I can parse it using beautifulsoup but I get this error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-f32d00599677> in <module>
      3 for file in os.listdir(path):
      4     with open(os.path.join(path, file), "r") as fname:
----> 5         txt = fname.read()

~/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/codecs.py in decode(self, input, final)
    320         # decode input (taking the buffer into account)
    321         data = self.buffer + input
--> 322         (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
    323         # keep undecoded input until the next call
    324         self.buffer = data[consumed:]

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x92 in position 2893: invalid start byte
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c  - does that help?

Comment: No i still get the same error with the codecs.open

Answer (score 4):

There are various approaches to dealing with text data with unknown encodings.  However in this case, as you intend pass the data to Beautiful Soup, the solution is simple: don't bother trying to decode the file yourself, let Beautiful Soup do it.  Beautiful Soup will [automatically decode bytes to unicode](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#encodings).

In your current code, you read the file in text mode, which means that Python will assume that the file is encoded as UTF-8 unless you provide an encoding argument to the `open` function.  This causes an error if the file's contents are not valid UTF-8.

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), "r") as fname:
        txt = fname.read()
```

Instead, read the html files in binary mode and pass the resulting `bytes` instance to Beautiful Soup.

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    with open(os.path.join(path, file), "rb") as fname:
        bytes_ = fname.read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(bytes_)
```

FWIW, the file currently causing your problem is probably encoded with cp1252 or a similar windows 8-bit encoding.

```
>>> '’'.encode('cp1252')
b'\x92'
```