# Invalid JSON characters after processing JSON file in Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, encoding, vuejs2, filereader

I am building a web-app where I can upload a JSON file, update it, then download it. The output JSON is not valid because some characters changed through the process. I don't know where I'm wrong because even when I only do upload => download without updates the JSON is still not valid...

This is how I read the uploaded JSON:

```
readFile: function () {
  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function(event) {
    this.json = JSON.parse(event.target.result);
  }.bind(this);
  reader.readAsText(this.file);
}
```

Then I can edit (or not) the `json` object. Then I can download it with `JSON.stringify(json)`.

When I try to read or validate the output JSON I get errors signaling invalid characters, for example:

- `Invalid characters in string. Control characters must be escaped` for some lines in my editor.
- `UnicodeDecodeError: ‘utf-8’ codec can’t decode byte 0xac in position X: invalid start byte` when I try to load it in python `with open('output.json') as json_file: data = json.load(json_file)`

Does using `JSON.parse` then `JSON.stringify` modifies the encoding or structure of the JSON? How can I avoid this effect?

**UPDATE:**

Original file can have some characters like `\u2013`, `\u2014`, `\u201d`, `\u00e7` but those characters are transformed into things like this � or invisible  characters in the output JSON, which I guess make it not valid.

Comment: This might help - 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c

Answer (score 2):

Try to add `'UTF-8'` as a second parameter to the `readAsText` function as follows :

```
   reader.readAsText(this.file,'UTF-8');
```

Comment: Unfortunatelly didn't work, I guess because utf-8 is already the default encoding value of `readAsText()`