# 0x85 windows 1252 breaks line if file opened with utf-8 encoding

Tags: parsing, encoding, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a file with an old format from the 70s used in Companies House (UK company registry).

I inherited a parser written 6 years ago which goes line by line and according to a set of conditions extracts the information from the line and inserts them into a dictionary.

There is a weird character that is breaking a line.

I copied this line to a new file `awk '{if(NR==33411) print $0}' PROD216_1950_ew_1.dat > broken` and opend `broken` in vim.

Turns out that weird character is read by vim a `<85>`.

The result is that everything after `MAYFIELD` is read as a new line.

Below the line in question:

```
000376702103032986930001        1993010119941024        193709          0105<BARRY ALEXANDER<GROSVENOR<<<<MAYFIELD 3<41 PLANTATION ROAD<THE PEAK<<HONG KONG<BANK EXECUTIVE<BRITISH<<
```

in vim becomes

```
000376702103032986930001        1993010119941024        193709          0105<BARRY ALEXANDER<GROSVENOR<<<<MAYFIELD <85>3<41 PLANTATION ROAD<THE PEAK<<HONG KONG<BANK EXECUTIVE<BRITISH<<
```

I am using `codecs` to read this file with a context manager, which I thought was the way of going about it -

Is there anything I am missing? What is that `<85>`?

```
with codecs.open(filepath, 'r', 'utf-8') as fh:
    for line in fh:
        linetype = determine_line_type(line)
        if linetype == 'header':
            continue
        elif linetype == 'company':
            do stuff...
        elif linetype == 'officer':
            do stuff...
```

Comment: An alternative to using vim would be `od -c broken`

Comment: I suspect that what you actually have is a `cp1252`-encoded file that is being run through a `latin1`-to-`utf8` conversion process before it gets to you. That is, in true `cp1252` there was a byte 0x85, then after the `latin1`-to-`utf8` process there was the two-byte sequence 0xC2 0x85, which `vim` interpreted as the character `U+0085`.

Comment: Ooooh thanks. This makes a lot of sense. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going around for some time [here](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/unicode.html#the-unicode-type) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c) I came up with this solution, which works.

```
with open(filepath, encoding='utf-8') as fh:

    for line in fh:

        byteline = bytearray(line, encoding='utf-8').replace(b'\xc2\x85', b'')
        line_clean = byteline.decode(encoding='utf-8')

       # do stuff with clean line.
```

Knowing that the byte sequence that breaks the string is b'\xc2\x85' (it is interpreted as an `...` ellipsis character.

First encode the string to an array of bytes with `bytearray`, then use `replace` method of the bytearray class, finally, decode the clean line using the `decode` method, which will return the string without the weird character from before the transformation.

Comment: You realize that using `encode` and `decode` with the same encoding string does absolutely nothing, right? You end up with the exact same string you started with.

Answer (score 1):

vim shows `<85>` to indicate a hex 85 byte that is invalid in the current encoding (i.e., the encoding it's using to decode the file).

My guess is that the file's encoding is [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252), in which hex 85 denotes the ellipsis character.

So the solution for your parser might be as simple as changing `'utf-8'` to `'cp1252'` in the `codecs.open` call.

Comment: this actually gives me the following error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 60: character maps to <undefined>`

Comment: @TytireRecubans if the goal is simply to read the file and not to get the proper characters, you can use `'latin-1'` for the encoding. It doesn't have any invalid bytes.