# reading .scp file with kaldi_io (python) UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python, speech-recognition, mfcc, kaldi

I am trying to read scp file with kaldi_io in python:

```py
mypath = r"/Users/Anas/Desktop/Parcours Centrale Lille/G3/Projet d'intégration/Toolbox/LibriSpeech_dev_clean_mfcc/raw_mfcc_dev_clean.1.scp"

for key,vec in kaldi_io.read_vec_flt_scp(mypath):
    print("mfcc of id ",key,"is equal to ",vec)
```

I get this error:

```py
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 76: invalid continuation byte
```

I don't know how to solve this problem

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Comment: Programmers never use utf-8 symbols in path. As well as spaces.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev I removed space and UTF8 but I still get the error

Comment: Sure, please provide the full stacktrace then.

Comment: @NikolayShmyrev check this question, I solved this problem but Iget a new error https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60323586/reading-scp-file-with-kaldi-io-python-unicodedecodeerror?noredirect=1#comment106786941_60323586