# How to filter none utf-8 HTML to get an utf-8 HTML?

Tags: python, html, utf-8, lxml, iconv

http://www.jcpjournal.org/journal/view.html?doi=10.15430/JCP.2018.23.2.70

If I use the following python code to parse the above HTML page, I will get `UnicodeDecodeError`.

```
from lxml import html
doc = html.parse(sys.stdin, parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
```

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 5365: invalid start byte
```

If I filter the input with `iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c` first, then run the same python code, I still get `UnicodeDecodeError`. What is a robust filter (without knowing the encoding of the input HTML) so that the filtered result always work with the python code? Thanks.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 5418: invalid continuation byte
```

EDIT: Here are the commands used.

```
$ wget 'http://www.jcpjournal.org/journal/view.html?doi=10.15430/JCP.2018.23.2.70'
$ ./main.py < 'view.html?doi=10.15430%2FJCP.2018.23.2.70'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 6, in <module>
    doc = html.parse(sys.stdin, parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 939, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3519, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1860, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1880, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1775, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1187, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 707, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 318, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 370, in lxml.etree._FileReaderContext.copyToBuffer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xb0 in position 5365: invalid start byte
$ iconv -f utf-8 -t utf-8 -c < 'view.html?doi=10.15430%2FJCP.2018.23.2.70' | ./main.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 6, in <module>
    doc = html.parse(sys.stdin, parser = html.HTMLParser(encoding='utf-8'))
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/lxml/html/__init__.py", line 939, in parse
    return etree.parse(filename_or_url, parser, base_url=base_url, **kw)
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 3519, in lxml.etree.parse
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1860, in lxml.etree._parseDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1880, in lxml.etree._parseFilelikeDocument
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1775, in lxml.etree._parseDocFromFilelike
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 1187, in lxml.etree._BaseParser._parseDocFromFilelike
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 601, in lxml.etree._ParserContext._handleParseResultDoc
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 707, in lxml.etree._handleParseResult
  File "src/lxml/etree.pyx", line 318, in lxml.etree._ExceptionContext._raise_if_stored
  File "src/lxml/parser.pxi", line 370, in lxml.etree._FileReaderContext.copyToBuffer
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/codecs.py", line 322, in decode
    (result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 5418: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: I have no problem read it directly from web page `r = requests.get(url)` and `doc = html.fromstring(r.content)`. What do you have in `sys.stdin` ? `parse()` needs `filename` or `url` - if you use filename or url then problem can be in this string, not in HTML from server.

Comment: I downloaded the file by wget. Then, read the downloaded file from stdin in python using the 2 lines of the python code shown.

Comment: how do you run it ? `echo "filename.html" | your script` ?

Comment: `myscript < filename.html`

Comment: it seems file is in `latin1`, not `utf8`. Use `cat filename.html | iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 | myscript`. See my answer.

Comment: I can not afford to know each input file's encoding. I need a solution that I don't need to know the specific encoding.

Comment: then run it with different encoding and catch errors - when one encoding generate error then parse it again with different encoding. Usually pages use three encoding `utf-8`, `latin1` or `cp1250` (eventually some modifications for native chars - like `latin2` for Central Europe). There is also python module `chardet` (char detections) which is used by `requests` to recognize encoding. So you can read file using `open()`, `read()`, in bytes mode, detect encoding and convert to bytes to string.

Comment: see in my answer example which use `try/except` to test it with different encodings.

Answer (score 1):

After digging I found that this file is not in `utf-8` but in `latin1` and problem has `sys.stdin` which uses `utf-8`. But you can't change encoding directly in `sys.stdin`. You have to use `sys.stdin` to create new stream with new encoding.

**main-latin1.py**

```
import sys
import io
from lxml import html

#input_stream = sys.stdin # gives error 
input_stream = io.TextIOWrapper(sys.stdin.buffer, encoding='latin1')
doc = html.parse(input_stream)

print(html.tostring(doc))
```

And now you can run

```
cat  'view.html?doi=10.15430%2FJCP.2018.23.2.70' | python main-latin1.py
```

---

**EDIT:** You can also convert it in console with `iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8`

```
cat  'view.html?doi=10.15430%2FJCP.2018.23.2.70' | iconv -f latin1 -t utf-8 | python main-utf8.py
```

**main-utf8.py**

```
import sys
from lxml import html

doc = html.parse(sys.stdin)

print(html.tostring(doc))
```

---

**BTW:** It has no problem to read it directly from page using `requests`

```
import requests
from lxml import html

r = requests.get('http://www.jcpjournal.org/journal/view.html?doi=10.15430/JCP.2018.23.2.70')

doc = html.fromstring(r.text)

print(html.tostring(doc))
```

---

**EDIT:** You can read data as bytes and use `for`-loop and `try/except` to decode with different encoding.

You run it without `<`

```
myscript filename.html
```

---

```
import sys
from lxml import html

# --- function ---

def decode(data, encoding):
    try:
        return data.decode(encoding)
    except:
        pass

# --- main ---

# only for test
#sys.argv.append('view.html?doi=10.15430%2FJCP.2018.23.2.70')

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print('need file name')
    exit(1)

data = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()

for encoding in ('utf-8', 'latin1', 'cp1250'):
    result = decode(data, encoding)
    if result:
        print('encoding:', encoding)
        doc = html.fromstring(result)
        #print(html.tostring(doc))
        break
```

---

**EDIT:** I tried to use module `chardet` (char detection) which uses `requests` but it gives me `windows-1252` (`cp1252`) instead of `latin1`. But for some reason `requests` has no problem to get it correctly.

```
import sys
from lxml import html
import chardet

# only for test
#sys.argv.append('view.html?doi=10.15430%2FJCP.2018.23.2.70')

if len(sys.argv) == 1:
    print('need file name')
    exit(1)

data = open(sys.argv[1], 'rb').read()

encoding = chardet.detect(data)['encoding']
print('encoding:', encoding)

doc = html.fromstring(data.decode(encoding))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could filter the input using `str = unicode(str, errors='ignore')` as suggested in [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c). This is not always desirable since unreadable characters will be dropped, but it may be fine for your use case.

Or [it seems](https://lxml.de/parsing.html) lxml can use `encoding='unicode'` in certain cases. Have you tried that?

Comment: I read the input from stdin. I don't call unicode directlyl. Where should I call `unicode(str, errors='ignore')`? How to modify the lxml code so that it will be robust with respect to any encoding? BTW, `encoding='unicode'` of lxml does not work (I don't use `tostring`).