# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 972: invali d start byte

Tags: python, operating-system, subprocess, decode, chdir

I want to run commands using **subprocess** but it throws error when I change directory

> error as UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in
> position 972: invali d start byte

```
  import os
  import subprocess
  while True:
      command = input(">> ")
      cdcommand = command.split(" ")
      if cdcommand[0] == "cd":
         os.chdir(cdcommand[1])
      else:
          result = subprocess.check_output(command , shell = True)
          print (result.decode())
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Comment: no it does not i dont understand i need it asap and anyhow

Comment: You need to show us what you're giving as input to this program when you get that error.