# How to solve UnicodeDecodeError when reading csv

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to open a csv file with pandas but i get this error:

```
test_tweets = pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\22587\Downloads\data\test_tweets.csv")

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xa0 in position 75: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Comment: I can suggest you to check the file and its encoding. Pandas will try to read this file in utf8 encoding but it possible can any other ancondinds. You can pass second argument to your function in that way: `encoding="cp1251"`. List of available encodings https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings

Comment: Please also take a look on this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18171739/unicodedecodeerror-when-reading-csv-file-in-pandas-with-python

Answer (score 1):

`0xa0` is the non breaking space. You maybe copied your data from a website and there was such an invisible character