# Errors when trying to read csv file into pandas data frame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I am fairly new to working with Python so forgive me if this is an obvious issue but when attempting to read my csv file into a data frame I get the following errors:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1119, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1244, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1259, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1450, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 11: invalid start byte

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\keegan.olson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\keegan.olson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 460, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\keegan.olson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1198, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "C:\Users\keegan.olson\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2157, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 847, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 862, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 941, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1073, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_column_data
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1126, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_tokens
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1244, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._convert_with_dtype
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1259, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._string_convert
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 1450, in pandas._libs.parsers._string_box_utf8
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x94 in position 11: invalid start byte
```

Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you put the code and a snippet of the file so that we can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Does it solve your problem? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c

Comment: seems like your csv file contains a utf-16 character

Comment: It was the utf-16 character issue - thank you guys so much! :)