# How to fix issue while appending a csv file

Tags: python, web-scraping

Hey I am scraping information of the steam store for some machine learning project.
I am iterating through the store page and going through each game and getting the name, review, date, developer and tag.
This is how I am adding info to my csv file.

```
    row_content = [name, review, date, developer, tags]
    append_list_as_row('steam_data.csv', row_content)
```

When I add around 10 or so row and access the csv file there is no issue. But as soon as there is more than that I get this error:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 9: invalid start byte

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your question has been asked before. Check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c

Comment: Search with the error message, `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 9: invalid start byte`, There will be enough information to help you understand what the error means. Welcome to SO please read [mre], [ask] and the other links found on those pages.