# Error while converting byte to string in python

Tags: python, arrays, encryption, byte, public-key-encryption

this is the duction where datajs is a json

```
def encrypt(datajs, pub_key):
        keyPub = RSA.importKey(pub_key)  # import the public key
        cipher = Cipher_PKCS1_v1_5.new(keyPub)
        # print(cipher.encrypt.__doc__)
        cipher_text = cipher.encrypt(datajs.encode())  # now we have the cipher
      
        cipher_text = cipher_text.decode()
     
        print(type(cipher_text))
        print(cipher_text)
        return cipher_text
```

this is the error showing

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "C:\Users\rahul.cs\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 106, in <module>
     encrypted = encrypt(datajs, pubkey)
   File "C:\Users\rahul.cs\PycharmProjects\pythonProject3\main.py", line 63, in encrypt
     cipher_text = cipher_text.decode()
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x95 in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c)

Comment: first you could check what encoding has char with code `0x95` - probably it is `Latin1`, `cp1250` or `ISO-8859`

Comment: `0x95` for `cp1250` it gives me `•` - see `b'\x95'.decode('cp1250')` - so you have data in `cp1250` and try `cipher_text.decode("cp1250")`

Comment: Calling `decode()` on that bytes object makes no sense and the error is a reflection of that fact. The result of encryption is a sequence of arbitrary bytes, not the encoding of a string. If you must convert the result to a string the standard method is to use base64 encoding. Depending in the specific use case you may want to use url-safe base64 encoding.