# UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position 11: invalid start byte

Tags: python

I am trying to read a CSV file from Google Drive with Pandas library.
However, I get the following error:

> UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xae in position
> 11: invalid start byte

I downloaded the data successfully and stored it in "/content/data" (=working directory).

To read the data I do the following:

```py
file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file.txt') 
# /content/data/file.txt

df = pd.read_csv(file1, delimiter='\t')
```

And that's where I get the error. What is the problem here?

I already tried the proposed solutions here: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0x9c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12468179/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x9c).
However, I still get the same error.

Comment: It seems that the file is not encoded with "UTF-8". You have to find out the right encoding, e. g. with an advanced text editor which can show and change the encoding.

Comment: You should be able to duplicate without pandas: `open(file1).read()`. if not, then `sys.stdin.encoding` would be a good guess on its encoding.

Comment: @MichaelButscher It is UTF-8 encoding. I checked.

Comment: @tdelaney I get the same error message with open(file1).read().

Comment: You added your question to review following the last edit but all you added to the question is *"I tried the solutions in that question and it didn't work"* but you didn't even showed ***what*** you tried and you ***never*** posted a [mre] of the file giving you this error. How can anyone help you except pointing to that duplicate quesiton?

Answer (score -2):

use encoding = 'unicode_escape',

```
file = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'file.txt') 
# /content/data/file.txt

df = pd.read_csv(file1, encoding= 'unicode_escape')
```

Comment: Why unicode_escape specifically? Given that the bad character isn't in the ascii range, we are pretty much guaranteed its not unicode_escape.

Comment: I tried this already and I get the following error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 6432-6433: malformed \N character escape