# Python File not found error

Tags: python, filenotfoundexception

I have a folder with different subfolders in it. I have to iterate through all the files and check for the occurrences of John and Jose and replace with Mikel and Mourinho respectively.

This is the script I have written in Python. It is working fine but when I encounter a `.gif` file it is giving me an error and it is not iterating further.

Can you please tell me why?

The error is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sid\Desktop\script.py", line 33, in <module>
    os.chmod(path ,stat.S_IWRITE)
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified:'C:\Users\sid\Desktop\test\\images/ds_dataobject.gif.bak'
```

My code:

```
import os,stat
import fileinput
import sys

rootdir ='C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop\test'
searchTerms={"John":"Mikel", "Jose":"Mourinho"}

def replaceAll(file,searchExp,replaceExp):
    for line in fileinput.input(file, inplace=1):
        if searchExp in line:
            line = line.replace(searchExp,replaceExp)
        sys.stdout.write(line)

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        path=subdir+'/'+file
        print(path)
        os.chmod(path ,stat.S_IWRITE)
        for key,value in searchTerms.items():
            replaceAll(path,key,value)
        os.chmod(path,stat.S_IREAD)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use a raw string or Double blackslashes `\\`:

Without `\\` or raw string `'\t'` is converted to a tab space:

```
>>> print 'C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop\test'
C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop   est
```

With raw string:

```
>>> print r'C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop\test'
C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop\test
```

Double blackslashes:

```
>>> print 'C:\\Users\\spemmara\\Desktop\\test'
C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop\test
```

**Update:**

> 'C:\Users\sid\Desktop\test\images/ds_dataobject.gif.bak'

Looking at the error you're trying to mix `\` and `/` in a single path, better use `os.path.join`:

```
path = os.path.join(subdir, file)
```

Comment: The code is working. It is replacing the files that have Jose with Mourinho but when there is a .gif file it is giving an error. So is it the problem of the raw string

Comment: i have tried it with other folders also say , C:\Users\spemmara\Desktop\Source. Even for this folder the code is working. It is replacing, if it is the problem that u mentioned, then it should not give an error right

Comment: The gifs is another problem unrelated with the rawstring

Comment: @Wolf It works with `'Users\spemmara\Desktop\Source'` because this string doesn't contains any special characters like `\t`, `\a` etc

Comment: @Wolf Instead of using `path=subdir+'/'+file` use `path = os.path.join(subdir, file)`.

Comment: @hcwhsa thanks man os.path.join did the trick. But now there is another error.

Comment: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 545: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Wolf Please post that as a new question and [mark this one as solved](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: ya sure man thanks again. I would be much more grateful if u can solve that

Answer (score 0):

In addition to hcwhsa's answer, you can also work it the hard way, by using double backslashes:

```
rootdir = 'C:\\Users\\spemmara\\Desktop\\test'
```

I lost my crystal ball yesterday, but i guess another thing that is giving you problems, is because when your program founds a `gif` file, you're trying to write text to it.

If you don't want to do it, just test it with a condition:

```
for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        path=subdir+'/'+file
        print(path)
        os.chmod(path ,stat.S_IWRITE)
        if '.gif' not in path:
            for key,value in searchTerms.items():
                replaceAll(path,key,value)
        os.chmod(path,stat.S_IREAD)
```