# Russian symbols in Python output corrupted (ENCODING)

Tags: python, encoding, utf-8, cyrillic, mojibake

I parsed a HTML document and have Russian text in it. When I'm trying to print it in [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29), I get this:

```
ÐÐ»ÑÐ±Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ð³Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ð¸Ð¹ Ð¿ÑÐ½Ñ
```

I tried to decode it and I get ISO-8859-1 encoding. I'm trying to decode it like that:

```
print drink_name.decode('iso8859-1')
```

But I get an error. How can I print this text, or encode it in [Unicode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode)?

Comment: You don't encode it to unicode, you decode it to unicode

Comment: Please include the code that you use to parse the HTML document in the first place, so we can help you not make this mistake in the first place.

Comment: The answer can be [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character). It helped me.

Answer (score 4):

You have a [Mojibake](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake); UTF-8 bytes decoded as Latin-1 or CP1251 in this case.

You can repair it by reversing the process:

```
>>> print u'ÐÐ»ÑÐ±Ð½Ð¸ÑÐ½ÑÐ¹ Ð½Ð¾Ð²Ð¾Ð³Ð¾Ð´Ð½Ð¸Ð¹ Ð¿ÑÐ½Ñ'.encode('latin1').decode('utf8')
Клубничный новогодний пунш
```

(I had to copy the string from the original post source to capture all the non-printable bytes in the Mojibake).

The better method would be to *not incorrectly decoding* in the first place. You decoded the original text with the wrong encoding, use UTF-8 as the codec instead.

If you used `requests` to download the page, do not use `response.text` in this case; if the server failed to specific codec then the HTTP RFC default is to use Latin-1, but HTML documents often embed the encoding in a `<meta>` header instead. Leave decoding in such cases to your parser, like BeautifulSoup:

```
response = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)  # pass in undecoded bytes
```

Comment: yes, this works. Thanks. I'll accept the answer in 10 minutes.

Comment: print drink_name.encode('latin1') even this works good. Also, how do you know that this is a Mojibake?

Comment: @aaaapppp: that only works if your terminal is configured to UTF-8. You cannot rely on that always.