# Encoding problem while web scraping Python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, python-requests, cyrillic

Do u know, why am I getting this **ID ÐÐ¾ÑÐ ÐµÐµÑÑÑÐ°** instead of getting **ID ГосРеестра**. I know that there is some issue with encoding, because it's cyrillic. Have no idea how to solve it.

Scraping web-page is [link](https://opi.dfo.kz/p/ru/DfoObjects/objects/teaser-view/26730?OptionName=ExtraData)

My code is:

```
dfo_url = "https://opi.dfo.kz/p/ru/DfoObjects/objects/teaser-view/26730?OptionName=ExtraData"
r = requests.get(dfo_url)

tree = html.fromstring(r.content)
tr_elements = tree.xpath('//tr')
#Create empty list
col=[]
i=0
#For each row, store each first element (header) and an empty list
for t in tr_elements[2]:
    i+=1
    name=t.text_content()

    print ('%d:"%s"'%(i,name))
    col.append((name,[]))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may fix it, try to do this right before the print:

```
name.encode(encoding='UTF-8',errors='strict')
```

Or try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869933/russian-symbols-in-python-output-corrupted-encoding) link.

Comment: @Dias take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26869933/russian-symbols-in-python-output-corrupted-encoding)

Comment: No problem, if you want you can accept my answer, i will update it with the link :) @Dias