# UPDATE: THE ISSUE IS FROM THE INSTRUCTOR txt file trying to import into python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Script would not run for attempting to import/read txt file. I have included the error message. It is a text file that i am trying to import

```
#Text Script:
import csv 
import pandas as pd

def read_file(network_data):
    data=[]
    for line in file:        
        data.append(line.strip())
    return data
if __name__=="__main__":
    file = open("network_data.txt", 'r')
data = pd.read_csv("network_data.txt")
print(data)


ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\~1.SAD\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_1204/4012165591.py in <module>
     10 if __name__=="__main__":
     11     file = open("network_data.txt", 'r')
---> 12 data = pd.read_csv("network_data.txt")
     13 print(data)
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 2 fields in line 3, saw 3
```

Comment: Did you get any errors? Please update your questions to include the errors, and the traceback that indicates where in the code those errors were raised

Comment: The first or last few lines of the trace will relate to a line in your file,  we just need that part. not the whole trace.

Comment: Is your `"network_data.txt"` a csv file? Are you ware that you are opening a file without closing it? And that your function `read_file` is not used?

Comment: You never call `read_file()`

Comment: And in `read_file` you don't use the `network_data` parameter.

Comment: @3DspatialUser it is a text file; and how is read_file not used?

Comment: If you want to create a pandas df, there's no need to read the file into a list.

Comment: your last two lines are not indented when they should be and pandas opens and closes files itself. You probably can't read from an open file with pandas.

Comment: It's not used because you never call the function.

Comment: If it's not a CSV file, why are you trying to use `pd.read_csv()`?

Comment: @user16760437 In the end, do you want `data` to be a list of rows or a pandas dataframe?

Comment: @Barmer a txt file is basically the same as an txt file with a little more order inside and his function is useless because pandas will do everything anyway

Comment: @Barmar how would this be fixed?

Comment: Print the first few rows of your text file. Probably it is not a proper csv (what you are trying to read) or you have to define the separator with (`sep=','`) in the `pd.read_csv` function.

Comment: `if __name__ == '__main__': with open("network_data.txt") as f: read_file(f)`

Comment: @3DspatialUser unfortunately that did not work

Comment: @Barmar that did not work unfortunately

Comment: You also need to fix the function to use `for line in network_data:`

Comment: @Barmar how would that be done in this case?

Comment: @JeffUK I have included the errors. Thanks

Comment: @Vorgon How would it be coded in that case?

Answer (score 1):

If the file isn't a CSV file, you can't use `pd.read_csv()`.

```
def read_file(network_data):
    with open(network_data) as f:
        return [line.strip() for line in f]

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = read_file("network_data.txt")
```

Comment: If the file doesn't use UTF-8 encoding, you need to specify the encoding as an argument to `open()`.

Comment: I am very perplexed as to why i am still receiving error messages. Would the issue be with my text file?

Comment: It is a text file

Comment: I know that. There are different ways to encode text files. Python defaults to `UTF-8`. If it's something else, you have to tell it.

Comment: How would i specify? Thank you

Comment: `open(network_data, encoding="whatever")`

Comment: Replace `whatever` with the correct encoding, such as `iso-8859-1`

Comment: "I am very perplexed as to why i am still receiving error messages"  What error messages?!

Comment: @JeffUK He had posted a comment with `UnicodeDecodeError`, then deleted it.

Comment: @JeffUK UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 4008: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @Barmar UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 4008: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @user16760437 Google the error message: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598350/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8d-in-position-7240-cha

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42019117/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-0x8f-in-position-xxx-char

Comment: @Barmar Hi, ```file = open("network_data.txt", encoding="utf8")``` no error appeared after that