# selecting columns from csv file error

Tags: python, csv, multiple-columns

I have a CSV file with 20501 rows and 26 columns. I want to select 5 column and 9 columns data. 
Here is what i have

```
import csv 
filename = 'feed_data.csv'
f = open(filename)
readCSV = csv.reader(f, delimiter=',')
names = []
confidence_score = []
for row in readCSV:
    names.append(row[8])
    confidence_score.append(row[4])
```

here is the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/raady/PycharmProjects/feeder_Classification/test.py", line 10, in <module>
for row in readCSV:
File "C:\Users\raady\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1009: character maps to <undefined>
```

how to rectify the error? 
I don't want to use pandas.

Is there any way that both columns can be copied only to one variable, instead of names and confidence_score seperately?

Edit:
I have installed python 3.6 and pycharm environment. I have installed all the packages from the pycharm environment.

Edit 2: 
I have tried in the suggested [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character) by modifying `f=open(filename,encoding='utf8')`, but I still have the error `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 934: invalid start byte`. 
The CSV file has been encoded in utf8.

Edit 3: 
I slightly modified code like this

```
import csv
filename = 'feed_data.csv'
# filename = 'test.csv'

with open(filename) as csvfile:
   readCSV = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',')
   data2 = []
   for row in readCSV:
       data = []
       data.append(row[14]) # appending names
       data.append(row[5])  # appending confidence
       data2.append(data)

   print(data2)
```

I am adding the two files [test.py](https://expirebox.com/download/71d23a3ca01123418ceec403cac34a1c.html) and [feed_data](https://expirebox.com/download/baaacd9b04bfceb0038d72e7472b9a00.html)( directly downloaded from kaggle). When I try with test.py it is working fine and I am able to select required column data but not with feed_data.py and it gives the error mentioned above.

Comment: Do you know encoding type of file in question?

Comment: I have mentioned utf8 as encoding type and it gives me this error, UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x89 in position 934: invalid start byte

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: I have tried mentioning encoding f=open(filename,encoding = 'utf8') then i get the error as mentioned as comment

Comment: I am using python 3.6 , will this information help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer moved from a question edit:

> A little modification helped
>
> ```
> with open(filename, encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') as csvfile:
> ```
>
> The issue is with the database file, The information regarding the
>   actual encoding technique is missing. Tried with the available
>   encoding formats by checking with help of visual studio code. Some row
>   data are corrupted and are ignored with the above command.