# Getting exception while opening files in flask

Tags: python, flask, postman

I'm getting error when i make postman request to my api when trying to read files from a directory.

```
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    print(cwd)
    cwd = cwd.replace('\\','/')
    print(cwd)
    path = cwd + "/training_data/"
    print(path)
    try:

        for files in os.listdir(path):
            data = open(path + files,'r').readlines()
            bot.train(data)

    except Exception as e:
        return jsonify("Error while opening file",path,cwd,os.listdir(path))
```

I'm getting the following exception:

```
[
"Error while opening file",
"C:/Users/RakeshS/Desktop/app/training_data/",
"C:/Users/RakeshS/Desktop/app",
[
    "code.txt",
    "deputation1.txt",
    "football.txt",
    "Greeting.txt",
    "internetaccess.txt",
    "intravels.txt",
    "sentiment.txt",
    "system.txt"
]]
```

Why is it not able to open the file and read data when i'm getting all the list of files inside the directory?

Comment: Did you tried to print the **actual exception?**

Comment: yes getting this 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1459: character maps to <undefined>'

Comment: **Why is it not able to open the file and read data when i'm getting all the list of files inside the directory?** The issue is not with the `FilePermission`. That is why you were able to list the files on the directory. The issue is with the file encoding. You should pass the encoding of the file with  `open(path + files,'r', encoding="your_file_encoding")`. I will also recommend you to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36159610/6699447) answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is complete solution to your problem:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify
import os
app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    cwd = os.getcwd()
    path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), 'training_data')
    try:
        for file in os.listdir(path):
            path_and_file = os.path.join(path, file)
            data = open(path_and_file, 'r').readlines()
            print(data)  # To print everything from a file
        return jsonify("Files successfully opened", path, cwd, os.listdir(path))

    except:
        return jsonify("There was error opening files", path, cwd, os.listdir(path))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Here is the output:

[image: Response of postman]

**Explanation**:

In my example, I put it on `/` route, but you can put it where ever you want.

Whenever I go to `/` route, I get JSON response. `os.getcwd()` gets me current directory, but I join two paths using [`os.path.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) function. From python documentation:

> Join one or more path components intelligently.

You can read more on python documentation. Next, since I get the path to `training_data`, I need to join again path to `training_data` and file. And I return JSON data. If anything goes wrong, you can print traceback in `except` clause and also return data, so that flask doesn't raise error for returning no response to the user.

P.S.

`training_data` folder is in a same level as a your flask application.