# UnicodeEncodeError when concatenating text files in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file-io, text-files, python-unicode, corpus

I am a python beginner.
I am trying to add(concatenate) the text from all the 8 text files into one text file to make a corpus.
However, I am getting the error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7311: character maps to

```
 filenames = glob2.glob('Final_Corpus_SOAs/*.txt')  # list of all .txt files in the directory
 print(filenames)
```

output:
['Final_Corpus_SOAs\\1.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\2.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\2018 SOA Muir.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\3.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\4.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\5.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\6.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\7.txt', 'Final_Corpus_SOAs\\8.txt']

```
with open('output.txt', 'w',encoding="utf-8") as outfile:
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Output:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7311: character maps to undefined

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure of the encoding, you should declare it when you open the files, both for reading and writing:

```
encoding = 'utf8'    # or 'latin1' or 'cp1252' or...

with open('output.txt', 'w',encoding=encoding) as outfile:
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname, encoding=encoding) as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

If you are unsure or do not want to be bothered by encoding, you can copy the files at the byte level by reading and writing them as binary:

```
with open('output.txt', 'wb') as outfile:
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname, 'rb') as infile:
        for line in infile:
            outfile.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the encoding type while opening the file. Please see this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character?answertab=active#tab-top) for more information. As this was already answered here.

Add `encoding="utf8"` to you code like below

```
with open('output.txt', 'w', encoding="utf8") as outfile:
for fname in filenames:
    with open(fname) as infile:
        for line in infile:
        outfile.write(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer@Sabesh.I have tried the encoding="utf-8" as well as errors='ignore'.It is still showing the error "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7311: character maps to <undefined>".