# Does reading files in Python 3 with the kwarg errors='ignore' skip the character or the entire file when it can't read something that's encoded?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file

It to me there should be some sort of consequence for errors when reading a file that may or may not be in an particular encoding...for instance here I was advised to use the kwarg `errors='ignore'` to [ignore errors when reading a file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50709581/18149):

```
f = open(notesFile, 'r', encoding='utf8', errors='ignore') # errors='ignore' seems to clear up any encoding issues (I just hope it only skips characters...)
```

But I'm uncertain if the entire file is skipped or just that character in the file when being read...

Comment: easy to verify -- what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

It only ignores the encoding errors in the file, not the entire file ([Ignore errors handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.ignore_errors))