# Trying to convert DBF to Excel with Python, but in some lines there's UnicodeDecodeError

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

First time posting, any advice is welcome :)

I have quite a lot of data in DBF format. I want to export it to Excel. I did this with smaller files before and went great, now I want to do the same with a DBF that would write several hundred of thousands of rows in Excel. But I'm not sure how to handle this error:

---

```
from dbfread import DBF
import pandas as pd
import time

start = time.time()

name_file= "MyData.dbf"

file = open(name_file, encoding="utf-8")

l = []


rango = 1000
count = 0

for limit, i in zip(range(rango), DBF(name_file)):
            count += 1
            l.append(i)





file.close()
df = pd.DataFrame(l)


end = time.time()
lapse = str(round(end-start,2))

print(f"{rango} iterations where processed in {lapse} seconds, total counts: {count}")
```

---

The first 718 iterations were doing great. Everything works smoothly and I can export the data to Excel.

But then, if I set "rango" to 719 or more, I get this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 33: character maps to <undefined>
```

---

I'm looking for a way to skip the error so the loop can just continue adding data of the next iteration to the list. But the error happens at this very line:

```
for limit, i in zip(range(rango), DBF(name_file))
```

I'm new at coding and researched about error handling, but I'm not finding anything specific to this. Most things I tried makes the loop start over again from scratch. I also tried changing the encoding="utf-8", but nothing seems to work.

Comment: You can try to figure out the file encoding, or - alternatively - try file = open(filename, errors='ignore'). See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character

Comment: Thanks for you reply! I tried opening the file as you mentioned but sadly it didn't work. I also tried to figure out the file encoding but wasn't successful. Gonna find the way somehow