# Giving an error when extracting cities from a text using geograpy(Python)

Tags: python, windows, nltk, geography

I am trying to extract city name from a text but it is giving an error.
Here is my code:

```
import geograpy

text = 'I am from Delhi'

places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)

print(places.cities)
```

ERROR:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:/Users/M.B.C. Kadawatha/PycharmProjects/NewsFeed/NLP.py", line 17, in <module>
    places = geograpy.get_place_context(text=text)

  File "C:\Users\M.B.C. Kadawatha\PycharmProjects\NewsFeed\venv\lib\site-packages\geograpy\__init__.py", line 11, in get_place_context
    pc.set_cities()

  File "C:\Users\M.B.C. Kadawatha\PycharmProjects\NewsFeed\venv\lib\site-packages\geograpy\places.py", line 137, in set_cities
    self.populate_db()
  File "C:\Users\M.B.C. Kadawatha\PycharmProjects\NewsFeed\venv\lib\site-packages\geograpy\places.py", line 30, in populate_db
    for row in reader:
  File "C:\Users\M.B.C. Kadawatha\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 274: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: I install geograpy through `python3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/reach2ashish/geograpy.git` and your code can be run successfully.

Comment: I used this command pip3 -m pip install git+https://github.com/reach2ashish/geograpy.git
But when I ran that command, The result would be :
Usage:
  pip <command> [options]

no such option: -m

Comment: It's `python3 -m`, not `pip3 -m`.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 It is giving this error that why I decided to use pip3  'python3' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: or just use `pip install git+https://github.com/reach2ashish/geograpy.git`

Comment: Still getting this error :- return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 274: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar what is the file name in here and where to put this                                                    
 file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")

Comment: Try adding `#!/usr/bin/python3`, `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-`(two lines) in the start of your python script file.

Comment: @keineahnung2345 getting this error:-   return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 274: character maps to <undefined>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be a bug in the package `geograpy`.

In `geograpy/places.py`, revise:

```
with open(cur_dir+"/data/GeoLite2-City-Locations.csv", "rb") as info:
```

to

```
with open(cur_dir+"/data/GeoLite2-City-Locations.csv", "r", encoding="utf-8") as info:
```

And the problem of encoding should go away.