# Get header of csv file

Tags: pandas, csv, export-to-csv, reader

I have 3000 Excel files. I want to get headers of each file and store it as a csv. However, I am running into a parsing error:

```
 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfa in position 1: invalid start byte
```

I have already seen this post. It does not solve the problem: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

```
import glob
import pandas as pd

all_files = glob.glob("Converted Excels/*.xlsx")
file = all_files[0]

#Try 1
columns = []
with open(file, "r") as csv_file:
    csv_reader = csv.reader(csv_file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_reader:
        columns.append([row])
        break

#Try 2
df = pd.read_csv(file, header=0, nrows=1)
df
```

Here is an example file. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/194QD14g_L0NQK6j3yO2Et2ZzycfQDzJXu7vdlr20owA/edit?usp=sharing

I converted this to Excel from a PDF. But during conversion, I had specified encoding="utf8".

How can I get the header from this file?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: `df = pd.read_csv('2011 abril 1.csv - 2011 abril 1.csv')` just worked for me..

Comment: `b'\x9d'.decode('cp437')` gives `¥` - so maybe your file is in `CP437`, not in `UTF8` and you have to use correct `endcoding` when you read it.

Comment: @furas, sorry. I updated the proper error code.

Comment: @Erfan, can you please explain that notation?

Comment: I also download file from link and `read_csv('2011 abril 1.csv - 2011 abril 1.csv')` works for me too. Linux Mint, Python 3.7, pandas 0.24.1

Comment: `0xFA` is `ú` in encoding `Windows-1252` - so maybe you should use `encoding='windows1252'` when you load files. See: https://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html

Comment: BTW: `.xlsx` is not csv file. You can't use `read_csv()` or module `csv` to read `.xlsx`. Use `read_excel()`. As I know `.xlsx` is zip file with file xml inside.

Comment: @furas Oh! "df = pd.read_excel(file)" solved the problem. Can you please post that as an answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.xlsx` is not CSV file. You can't use `pandas.read_csv()` or module `csv` to read `.xlsx`.

Use `pandas.read_excel()` or modules for excel files. See: [www.python-excel.org](http://www.python-excel.org/)

As I know `.xlsx` is ZIP file with XML file inside - so you can also try to unzip it and read xml.