# how to read a csv file full of string of numbers to an numpy array

Tags: python, excel, file, numpy, csv

I have a csv file that includes 3 columns, and I need to import it to a numpy array, respectively.
The csv file is like:

```
Study ID     DWM     PVWM    GCA

980500221101     1   1   1

980500251101     0   0   1

980500271101     1   1   1

980500291101     1   0   0

980500301101     2   2   1
```

I tried

pandas : `pd.read_csv('filename.csv')`

and numpy : `np.genfromtxt('filename.csv',delimiter=',')`

and csv:

```
with open('filename.csv', newline='') as csvfile:
   reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
```

and got this error:
charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 639: character maps to

Comment: Possible duplicate of [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: Check out [`chardet.detect()`](https://chardet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#example-using-the-detect-function); once you know the encoding, you can give that to `pd.read_csv()`.