# How to read csv file using python that have multi line data in one field

Tags: python, csv

I have to parse CSV file that have multi line data using python

example source data 
col1,col2,col3
"data1","data2","data3"
**"data4
continue in next line"**,"data5","data6"
"data1","data2","data3"

when i read the data using csv reader it is getting failed with below error 
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 1256: character maps to

Comment: I tried it locally: Newlines in CSV are no problem for the csv module. Your UnicodeDecodeError ist most likely due to an encoding that differs from the default (usually UTF-8 is the default).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [csv read raises "UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode..."](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59082843/csv-read-raises-unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode)

Comment: @LydiavanDyke thank you so much this solved my issue