# Python re.sub does not replace newline

Tags: python, regex, replace, newline, python-re

I have some text like this:

```
<Row 1 Having A Text>
<Row 2 Having B Text>
<Row 3 Having C Text>
```

I am trying to remove  entirely and shift  up.

I have been trying to use this:

```
for line in fileinput.input(new_name, inplace=True): 
print (re.sub(r'<Row 2.*[\r\n]*', '', line.strip()))
```

However, this just results in the following:

```
<Row 1 Having A Text>

<Row 3 Having C Text>
```

And Row 3 does not move up. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that even though your regex matches and replaces the contents of `line` with an empty string (`''`), `print('')` will output a blank line. Instead of printing every line, print just the lines that don't start with `<Row 2`

```
for line in fileinput.input(new_name, inplace=True): 
    if not line.strip().startswith('<Row 2'):
        print(line)
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I tried doing this but now I am running into an issue where I have this error: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7725: character maps to <undefined>

What are the possible workarounds for inplace and encoding in fileinput?

Comment: @curioustea this might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character

Comment: Thank you Nick. I was able to get to a workaround eventually regarding that matter. Selecting your comment as the answer since it answered my initial question.

Comment: @curioustea I'm glad you got it resolved. If you couldn't find a solution on SO, it might be worth asking and self-answering a question on it. and thanks...

Answer (score 0):

`print()` outputs the LF even if the content is empty, so you replace 'Row 2' with an empty string, but since you still use `print`, you get an empty line on output.

You may check for an empty line:

```
for line in fileinput.input(new_name, inplace=True): 
    output = re.sub(r'<Row 2.*[\r\n]*', '', line.strip())
    if len(output) :
        print(output)
```