# python unable to start in virtual environment in VS code: UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I recently used windows' virtual environment to set up the environment in order to run PyTorch deep learning code.

Starting from the very simplistic code in PyTorch's official tutorial, I managed to run the code for the first time. However, after my first running and executing "python" in command line, it shows:

```
(venv) PS C:\Users\xxx\demo_pytorch\venv> python
Fatal Python error: initsite: Failed to import the site module
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site.py", line 579, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site.py", line 562, in main
    known_paths = venv(known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site.py", line 494, in venv
    addsitepackages(known_paths, [sys.prefix])
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site.py", line 349, in addsitepackages
    addsitedir(sitedir, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site.py", line 207, in addsitedir
    addpackage(sitedir, name, known_paths)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\site.py", line 163, in addpackage
    for n, line in enumerate(f):
  File "C:\Users\xxx\Miniconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 654: character maps to <undefined>
```

Can anyone tell me how to fix this? The default python in the VS code has been set as .\Scripts\python.exe

Comment: Check your local `.vscode/settings.json`, it should have a key-value pair called pythonPath, the value of which should be like `env_name\\Scripts\\python.exe`. You don't really need to change the default python in VS Code.

Comment: I checked it. It is correct. Otherwise, the first debugging would be wrong.

Comment: Do you have Unicode characters in your path? That error would come up because you're trying to feed Python text which can't be decoded during startup.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the file encoding caused this. If you have code:

```
file = open(filename)
```

you need to change it to:

```
file = open(filename, encoding="utf8")
```

you can refer to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character) page or [another](https://github.com/aerdem4/kaggle-quora-dup/issues/3) page for more information.