# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list convert

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't know good at python
I want to make a convert of .log files .txt in. html
I'm trying to pass the value as an array.
But he doesn't accept it. How can I fix this `TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not list`?
Thank you in advance

```
import txt_to_html
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\Sandy\\PycharmProjects\\untitled1'
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.log')]
txt_to_html.parse_txt(text_files)
```

Comment: argument `text_files` to `parse_txt` function should be string not list.

Comment: I need to do this with all the files in the folder. there are more than 100 of them

Comment: Okay. I posted solution below, please let me know if this help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use below code snippet to achieve what you want.

```
import txt_to_html
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\Sandy\\PycharmProjects\\untitled1'
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.log')]
for file in text_files:
      txt_to_html.parse_txt(file)
```

Comment: I get an error:    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 588: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: I feel the issue is with your file encoding. You can refer to this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character.

Comment: please tell me how to specify encoding

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, `txt_to_html.parse_txt` requires the text source, you are passing a list of files that it doesn't understand what to do.

Modify to -

```
import txt_to_html
import os
path = 'C:\\Users\\Sandy\\PycharmProjects\\untitled1'
text_files = [f for f in os.listdir(path) if f.endswith('.log')]
parsed_op = [txt_to_html.parse_txt(i) for i in text_files]

print(parsed_op[0]) // this will give you the output of first log file.
```

Comment: return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 588: character maps to <undefined>