# How can I combine two very simple datasets (keyword, numerical value) by summing values of the same keyword across the two files in Python 3.8?

Tags: python, python-3.x, database

Apologies in advance for not fully understanding how to format things on this website perfectly. As such, the tabs in my examples aren't so pretty.

I need to read the contents of two .txt files, each line containing a keyword and integer value delimited by tabs, and sum the values of common keywords between the two files; and then order the keywords from highest to lowest associated values (with values listed) in a new text file.

Let's say I have two .txt files:

```
eggs    25
beans    10
peas    30
oranges    15
```

```
eggs    15
pineapples    45
beans    35
peas    25
```

My desired output would resemble:

```
peas    55
beans    45
pineapples    45
eggs    40
oranges    15
```

In case of two values being shared, I would like to order the keywords alphabetically.

What is the most efficient and Pythonic way of going about this?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you have to read the files and then convert them to dataframe and add them

### First Text File

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\1.txt','r') as rf1:
    df1=rf1.readlines()

df1=pd.DataFrame(df1)
data=[df1[0].str.split()[i] for i in range(0,4)]
df1=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['items','amount'])
```

### Second txt file

```
with open(r'C:\Users\Arpit\Desktop\2.txt','r') as rf2:
    df2=rf2.readlines()

df2=pd.DataFrame(df2)
data=[df2[0].str.split()[i] for i in range(0,4)]
df2=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['items','amount'])
```

Now you can simply add the data

```
    items={}
    for index1,i in enumerate(df1['items']):
       for index2,j in enumerate(df2['items']):
         if i==j:
            items[i]=int(df1['amount'][index1])+int(df2['amount'][index2])

    ## For First DataFrame
    for index,i in enumerate(df1['items']):
        if i not in items.keys():
            items[i]=df1['amount'][index]

   ## For second DataFrame
   for index,j in enumerate(df2['items']):
    if j not in items.keys():
        items[j]=df2['amount'][index]

  ## Finally making the final DataFrame
  df=pd.DataFrame(items.values(),index=items.keys()).reset_index()
  df.columns=['items','amount']
  df
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you elaborate more specifically on what this code is doing, namely ```enumerate()``` function?

Comment: enumerate() is basically used to get the index along the value it is using at each iteration. And then I have created a dictionary in which firstly I am taking the duplicates and adding their values and adding it to the dictionary. Then I am checking for both dataframes non- duplicate values and adding those to the dictionary

Comment: How could I export this data to a .txt file of the same tab-separated layout?

Comment: Use  `numpy.savetxt()` . Refer to this link -  https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html

Comment: This solution seems to only be listing the data for df1.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219685/discussion-between-randall-ivan-carson-and-arpit).

Answer (score 1):

Using csv and counter modules

**Code**

```
import csv
from collections import Counter

with open('f1.txt', 'r') as f1, open('f2.txt', 'r') as f2:
  # shown input has multiple spaces between fields
  reader1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)
  reader2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=' ', skipinitialspace=True)

  # Use dictionary comprehension to
  # convert to dictionary
  #    converting second value in each row to int
  d1 = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in reader1}
  d2 = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in reader2}

# Use Counter to add common keys
cnts = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)

# Sort by value descending and alphabeical ascending
result = dict(sorted(cnts.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0])))
for k, v in result.items():
  print(k, v)
```

**Test**

File1.txt

```
eggs    25
beans    10
peas    30
oranges    15
```

File2.txt

```
eggs    15
pineapples    45
beans    35
peas    25
```

Output

```
peas 55
beans 45
pineapples 45
eggs 40
oranges 15
```

**Update**

Code updated based upon actual data example

Issues

- Posted code is multispace delimited
- Actual data is tab delimited
- Many rows in the real data (from comment) is not properly formatted as two-column fields
- Created a function to go line by line through the data to retrieve only valid fields
- Used data link in comment for files 1 & 2

*Code Update*

```
from collections import Counter

def get_data(filenm):
  '''
    Two column CSV tab delimited data
    vald - lines with valid data
    invalid - lines with invalid data (linenumber, data)
  '''
  valid, invalid = [], []
  with open(filenm, 'r', encoding="utf8") as f:
    for i, line in enumerate(f):
      row = line.rstrip().split('\t')
      if len(row) == 2:
        valid.append(row)  # Valid row of data
      else:
        invalid.append((i, line))

  return valid, invalid

valid1, invalid1 = get_data('agg1.txt')
valid2, invalid2 =get_data('agg2.txt')

# Convert Valid rows to dictionary
d1 = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in valid1}
d2 = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in valid2}

cnts = Counter(d1) + Counter(d2)
# Sort by value descending and alphabeical ascending
result = dict(sorted(cnts.items(), key=lambda kv: (-kv[1], kv[0])))

# Show first 10 lines of results
print('First 10 lines of results')
for i, (k, v) in enumerate(result.items()):
  print(k, v)
  if i > 10:
    break

# Show invalid data (line number and line)
print()
print('Invalid file 1')
print(*invalid1, sep = '\n')
print('Invalid file 2')
print(*invalid2, sep = '\n')
```

*Output Update*

```
First 10 lines of results
。 6397586
を 4450628
《 2948712
》 2948688
「 2295146
」 2294570
… 1843528
だ 1530958
いる 841602
こと 761052
？ 545826
する 458792

Invalid file 1
(5828, '\t\t\t946\n')
(24158, '133\n')
(24293, '132\n')
(30648, '87\n')
(37889, '58\n')
(46807, '37\n')
(51404, '\t\t\t30\n')
(53151, '27\n')
(54272, '26\n')
(54677, '25\n')
(55962, '24\n')
(57129, '23\n')
(70327, '13\n')
(71287, '12\n')
(73405, '11\n')
(76059, '10\n')
(76214, '10\n')
(82563, '8\n')
(83460, '8\n')
(85801, '7\n')
(88476, '6\n')
(88494, '6\n')
(94354, '5\n')
(94703, '5\n')
(97635, '4\n')
(110152, '3\n')
(110153, '3\n')
(110560, '3\n')
(111046, '3\n')
(117778, '2\n')
(117791, '2\n')
(117795, '\t\uf8f3\t2\n')
(117806, '2\n')
(118312, '2\n')
(119811, '2\n')
(119848, '2\n')
(134106, '1\n')
(134485, '1\n')
(134505, '1\n')
(136092, '1\n')
(136144, '1\n')
(136147, '1\n')
(139521, '1\n')
(139626, '1\n')
(139629, '1\n')
(139645, '1\n')
(139665, '1\n')
(139724, '1\n')
(139877, '1\n')
(139885, '1\n')
(139887, '1\n')
(139897, '1\n')
(139914, '1\n')
(139935, '1\n')
(139936, '1\n')
(139963, '1\n')
(139975, '1\n')
Invalid file 2
(5828, '\t\t\t946\n')
(24158, '133\n')
(24293, '132\n')
(30648, '87\n')
(37889, '58\n')
(46807, '37\n')
(51404, '\t\t\t30\n')
(53151, '27\n')
(54272, '26\n')
(54677, '25\n')
(55962, '24\n')
(57129, '23\n')
(70327, '13\n')
(71287, '12\n')
(73405, '11\n')
(76059, '10\n')
(76214, '10\n')
(82563, '8\n')
(83460, '8\n')
(85801, '7\n')
(88476, '6\n')
(88494, '6\n')
(94354, '5\n')
(94703, '5\n')
(97635, '4\n')
(110152, '3\n')
(110153, '3\n')
(110560, '3\n')
(111046, '3\n')
(117778, '2\n')
(117791, '2\n')
(117795, '\t\uf8f3\t2\n')
(117806, '2\n')
(118312, '2\n')
(119811, '2\n')
(119848, '2\n')
(134106, '1\n')
(134485, '1\n')
(134505, '1\n')
(136092, '1\n')
(136144, '1\n')
(136147, '1\n')
(139521, '1\n')
(139626, '1\n')
(139629, '1\n')
(139645, '1\n')
(139665, '1\n')
(139724, '1\n')
(139877, '1\n')
(139885, '1\n')
(139887, '1\n')
(139897, '1\n')
(139914, '1\n')
(139935, '1\n')
(139936, '1\n')
(139963, '1\n')
(139975, '1\n')
```

Comment: How could I use non-ASCII characters in a file using this method? I have both files opened in UTF-8, however the program still returns a UnicodeDecodeError at the line `d1 = {x[0]:int(x[1]) for x in reader1}`.

Comment: @RandallIvanCarson--Will take a look.  Could you either provide a link to your data example (with non-ascii) or update the data in [this example](https://repl.it/@DarrylGurganiou/sumtwocsv) i.e. f1.txt and f2.txt?

Comment: The files I am combining are two Japanese word use frequency reports of different sources, so I am apprehensive about providing a link even though they were already freely available, but I will anyway. [Here is one of them.](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MlWHECKp-v70Zvizj-YcN_Zu0_gG09wd/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: @RandallIvanCarson--see my updated answer (basically the additional portion with an update).

Comment: Unfortunately this solution has also returned a UnicodeDecodeError. Perhaps there is a difference between our operating systems or their settings.

Comment: @RandallIvanCarson--discovered it worked on Linux but had your error on Windows 10.  Anyway, I updated get_data and it now works on Windows 10 & Linux.  Problem was related to this post [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Comment: @RandallIvanCarson--issue seems to have been on Linux default encoding is UTF-8 while it's CP1252 on Windows.  Explicitly specifying UTF-8 in function get_data fixed the problem.  If interested see [Processing Text Files in Python 3](http://python-notes.curiousefficiency.org/en/latest/python3/text_file_processing.html#the-binary-option) for further details.