# cannot open files at BeatifulSoup lxml parser

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am trying to read the contents of an HTML file with `BeautifulSoup`, but I'm receiving an `UnicodeDecodeError`.

[image: I have the file in the project folder its an HTML file]

I also tried changing the parser to `html.parser` instead of the `lxml`  but it doesn't work.

however, if I use the `requests` library to request the URL, it works, but not if I read the HTML file locally.

**answer:**
I needed to add a Unicode and it was should have something like that: `with open('lap.html', encoding="utf8") as html_file:`

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a file to 'BeautifulSoup' instead you have to pass the content of the file.

try :
`content = html_file.read() source = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')`

Comment: add the encoding to file open [charmap' codec can't decode byte python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9233174/6602608)

Comment: Then edit your answer to the actual or let him mark mine, since i mentioned the coding standart already

Answer (score 0):

First of all, fix the soruce to source, then make a gap between the equal sign and the text and then find out, what might not be encodable by the coding standart you use, because that error refers to a sign which cant be decoded/encoded

Comment: I fix it you can  see the image now  ty

Comment: Yeah but you still have an exotic sign in this file which cant be coded, like some sign for a currency or a letter in russian or something like that. Either try to delete that, or change the coding standart. If both doesnt work, make a catch for it

Comment: how can I change the coding standard?

Comment: I see it works now, thats basically what i wanted to say