# UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2310: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python-3.x, windows, unicode

I have recently been working on Python and have started to face this issue even when I just start the Python Interactive terminal using the command prompt.
I referred [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character) but I have not been executing any python code as suggested in that question; but am just entering the python shell using `python` command inside a fresh command prompt (PS: I am using Windows 10)

The error I seem to face is:

```
C:\Users\>python
Python 3.8.5 (default, Sep  3 2020, 21:29:08) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] :: Anaconda, Inc. on win32

Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Failed calling sys.__interactivehook__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site.py", line 440, in register_readline
    readline.read_history_file(history)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\rlmain.py", line 165, in read_history_file
    self.mode._history.read_history_file(filename)
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyreadline\lineeditor\history.py", line 82, in read_history_file
    for line in open(filename, 'r'):
  File "D:\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 2310: character maps to <undefined>

>>>
```

I don't find any line where I can add the `"utf8"` in any suggested lines.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try deleting `.python_history` file which would be under `C:\Users\<user-name>\`.
There seem to be more gibberish in your history file.