# How to open multiple text files from an array?

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, arraylist, text

I want to open and read several text files. The plan is to find a string in the text files and print the whole line from the string. The thing is, I can´t open the paths from the array.
I hope it is unterstandable what I want to try.

```
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import join
from config import cred

path = (r"E:\Utorrent\Leaked_txt")
for filename in os.listdir(path):
    list = [os.path.join(path, filename)]
    print(list)

for i in range(len(list)-1):
    with open(str(list[i], "r")) as f:
        for line in f:
            if cred in line:
                print(line)
```

Thanks :D

Comment: When you say you can't open the paths from the array, what do you mean? What's the error you are getting?

Comment: I didn´t get an error but it also print nothing so I probably messed something up

Comment: You shouldn't use `list` as a variable name as it's a Python keyword.

Comment: Damn I should get more into python. My bad

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `os`, you can do something like this:

```
import os
from config import cred 

path = "E:/Utorrent/Leaked_txt"
files = [os.path.join(path, file) for file in os.listdir(path) if file.endswith(".txt")]

for file in files:
    with open(file, "r") as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            if cred in line:
                print(line)
```

### Edit

`os.listdir` only includes files from the parent directory (specified by `path`). To get the .txt files from all sub-directories, use the following:

```
files = list()
for root, _, f in os.walk(path):
    files += [os.path.join(root, file) for file in f if file.endswith(".txt")]
```

Comment: Thank for your reply, it worked put I also got this error: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7656: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: @t0xic - That's a completely different issue. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character). You might need a `try/except` blog where you try reading the file with multiple encodings.

Comment: Okay got it. One question left, how can I remove the "[]" because those got printed for every line?

Comment: Stil have an issue :( It only searches about 1/16th of the dictionary

Comment: What dictionary?

Comment: In "files =" I took all the paths from the text files and open/search them (around 12,5k text files). If I print "files" I only got around 250 txt files. As an example: I search for a string in the 250th + 251th text file it only finds the string in the 250th text file

Comment: `os.listdir` shows all the files in path (not including sub-directories). If you're trying to access all files within all sub-folders, use `os.walk`

Comment: That´s the problem, all the files are in the same folders with no sub-folders :(

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use glob when reading several files in a directory

```
import glob

files = glob.glob(r"E:\Utorrent\Leaked_txt\*.txt") # read all txt files in folder

for file in files: # iterate over files
    with open(file, 'r') as f: # read file
        for line in f.read(): # iterate over lines in each file
            if cred in line: # if some string is in line
                print(line) # print the line
```

Comment: Worked so far but I got this error now: Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 7656: character maps to <undefined>

Comment: If all your files are `UTF-8` then you can try adding the encoding: `with open(file , 'r', encoding='utf8') as f:`

Comment: nah, suddenly got this: Exception has occurred: UnicodeDecodeError
'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xfb in position 7685: invalid start byte

Comment: How are your files encoded, ASCII? You can also try adding `read()`

Comment: If I open them there is utf8, how can I check them?