# Python printing unicode characters instead of ASCII

Tags: python, windows, shell

I want to print an ASCII text but when I run the script, it throws me an error:

```
$ python test.py Traceback (most recent call last): 
   File "C:\Users\wooxh\Desktop\Materialy\XRichPresence\test.py", 
       line 1, in <module> print(""" File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\encodings\cp1250.py", 
           line 19, in encode return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0] UnicodeEncodeError: 
   'charmap' codec can't encode characters in position 2-4: character maps to <undefined>
```

Here's the code

```
print("""
██╗  ██╗██████╗ ██████╗  ██████╗
╚██╗██╔╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
 ╚███╔╝ ██████╔╝██████╔╝██║     
 ██╔██╗ ██╔══██╗██╔═══╝ ██║     
██╔╝ ██╗██║  ██║██║     ╚██████╗
╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝      ╚═════╝
""")
```

Comment: Remove the `encode` call.

Comment: It's printing encoded because you are encoding it...

Comment: Seems to work if you remove the `.encode("UTF-8")` at the end.

Comment: Why are you encoding it? `print` doesn't handle `bytes` (it just calls `str()` on them which ends up printing their `repr`), so if you need to write raw bytes in a specific encoding, you'll have to use `sys.stdout.buffer.write()`, but I'm unclear why you don't just `print` the string without encoding and let `print` (really `sys.stdout`) encode from text to bytes for you.

Comment: Voting to close, as caused by typo *(kinda)*

Comment: I Added the .encode call because it would throw me another error

Comment: @WooxHimself then update your post to highlight that error; you shouldn't arbitrarily add things to code.

Comment: @WooxHimself Then why did you not include the traceback?

Comment: @WooxHimself: Odds are that's because your terminal doesn't support UTF-8 (or at least, Python doesn't think it does). That's a configuration problem slightly outside of Python.

Comment: @WooxHimself: What version of Python do you have installed? Python 3.7 [supports a forced UTF8 runtime mode](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-540-forced-utf-8-runtime-mode) that might be enough to make this code work (Windows' `cmd.exe` runs in a non-UTF8 mode by default).

Comment: I edited the question to include the traceback OP posted on Taco's answer.

Comment: @WooxHimself: Assuming you're running in `cmd.exe` on Windows, can you run `chcp` in the `cmd.exe` terminal (not in Python) and report what it displays? For me, it's `Active code page: 437`, which means the `print` *should* work (or `sys.stdout.buffer.write('''the string'''.encode('cp437'))` to explicitly encode); I'm not 100% on how potentially UTF-8 coercion with a terminal using cp437 might interact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like Python is identifying your code page as 1250, which doesn't include the characters you're using. If `chcp` reports you're actually using code page 437 (common in `cmd.exe`) you can do:

```
import sys

sys.stdout.buffer.write("""
██╗  ██╗██████╗ ██████╗  ██████╗
╚██╗██╔╝██╔══██╗██╔══██╗██╔════╝
 ╚███╔╝ ██████╔╝██████╔╝██║     
 ██╔██╗ ██╔══██╗██╔═══╝ ██║     
██╔╝ ██╗██║  ██║██║     ╚██████╗
╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝  ╚═╝╚═╝      ╚═════╝
""".encode('cp437'))
```

to explicitly encode to the correct code page and write it. Otherwise, I'd suggest enabling Python's [forced UTF-8 runtime mode](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html#pep-540-forced-utf-8-runtime-mode), which should allow your original code (with no call to `encode`) to work (possibly dropping or replacing characters not representable by the terminal). All you'd change is your run command:

```console
> python -X utf8 test.py
```

or explicitly define `PYTHONUTF=1` in your environment to turn it on without a command line switch.