# Json UnicodeDecodeError 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 3621: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, json, utf-8

I'm loading a json file on my computer.
I can load it in without specifying the encoding on Kaggle, no, errors.
On my PC I get the error in the title.

```
with open('D:\soccer\statsbomb360\matches.json') as f:
    data = json.load(f, encoding = 'utf8')
```

Adding `errors = 'ignore'` or changing encoding to 'latin' doesn't work either.
I'm a bit lost on what to try next, can you give me an idea?

The json is from statsbombs freely available data.
Interestingly from the same dataset I have some files that give me this error on Kaggle/Colab but not on my pc, but there specifying `encoding = 'latin'` did the trick.

thank you!

Comment: Put the encoding parameter in the open

Comment: @MarkTolonen You are a lifesaver, this worked! So many people couldn't figure it out yesterday. Thanks! Do you want to add this as an answer?
I gladly accept it as solution!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try

```py
with open('D:\soccer\statsbomb360\matches.json', encoding="utf8") as f:
    data = json.load(f)
```

per @mark-tolonen

Also see this post: [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)