# Anaconda3 - cp1251.py: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1130: character maps to <undefined>

Tags: python, pip, anaconda, conda, requirements

I'm trying to install packages from requirements.txt with PIP inside a PIP created environment for YOLOv5 and stumble upon this message.

```
> File "C:\Users\username\anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
>     return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0] UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position
> 1130: character maps to <undefined>
```

Also this message erupts when trying to update PIP.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Answer (score -1):

Desperately deleting cp1251.py file in the directory I solved the problem.

Can somebody clarify why this worked ?