# Loading hugh amounts of json files, Error

Tags: python, json, file, file-handling

im new to programming and just started 7 days ago, i hope my queastion is not that stupid. I do not want to be the "Can someone code me this..." guy. To name a keyword or a method on the basis of which I can search further myself would already help me a lot.

I have a hughe amount (500000-1000000) Json files in a dictionary, all have the same formate. My goal is to load the files and to write some Values into another CSV file. I already started to write a code, but if im running it, it stops after ~80 files and gives the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Hauke\PycharmProjects\Json Merge\CSV.py", line 14, in <module>
    data = json.load(g)
  File "C:\Users\Hauke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\json\__init__.py", line 293, in load
    return loads(fp.read(),
  File "C:\Users\Hauke\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 8934: character maps to <undefined>
```

I do not really understand why? I guess it is becauze the program can not load so many json files? I know that the "if" part is really a mess, if it has no impact on my problem, you guys can ignore that part.

My Code:

```
import json
import os
import csv
import time

start = time.time()

for path, dirs, files in os.walk("Json"):
    for f in files:
        fileName = os.path.join(path, f)
        print(fileName)

        with open(fileName, "r") as g:
            data = json.load(g)


            if data.get("Retweeted") == True:
                name1 = data.get("ScreenName")
                rtstatus = data.get("RetweetedStatus")
                rtent = rtstatus.get("User")
                name = rtent.get("ScreenNameResponse")
                fields = [name1, name]
                with open("Import.csv", "a", newline="") as t:
                    writer = csv.writer(t)
                    writer.writerow(fields)

            if data.get("InReplyToScreenName") != "null":
                name2 = data.get("ScreenName")
                RPName = data.get("InReplyToScreenName")
                fields2 = [name2, RPName]
                with open("Import.csv", "a", newline="") as u:
                    writer2 = csv.writer(u)
                    writer2.writerow(fields2)


end = time.time()
print('Time taken for fun program: ', end - start)
```

Thanks for your help, I hope I'm not too stupid.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character try look at this and see if it helps?

Comment: Check what file throws the error and if it is in correct format

Answer (score 0):

`UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8d in position 8934: character maps to <undefined>`
it is a decoding issue. you could ignore the decoding issue or find out the issue part

```py
 with open(fileName, "r") as g:
  # data = json.load(g)
  data = g.read()
  data_str = data.decode("utf-8", errors='ignore')
  json.load(data_str)
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.load` is not efficient for loading a huge json file since it loads the whole file into memory before parsing.

You should use the "streaming" solution in order to parse huge json file, that means that you are going to parse it one chunk at a time instead of all the file at once.

```
import json

with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = json.loads(line)
```

- you can also the [ujson](https://github.com/ultrajson/ultrajson) library, it's basically the json library you know but faster (written in pure C).

Comment: This solution will work as long as the input files contain one json record per line. If that's not the structure, streaming remains a good idea but it would have to be adapted to match the data in the files.

Comment: Correct, thanks for mentioning this!