# Python, pyTelegramBotAPI, error send photo

Tags: python, py-telegram-bot-api

Why python write large error text ind cmd when i try send photo? I already google it. Nothing.

```
    bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=open(r'E:\site_work\telebot\img\samples\1.jpg'))
        bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, "Look photo", reply_markup=markup)
```

Error:

```
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1251.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x98 in position 1015: character maps to <undefined>
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is probably something to do with the format of the image. It is probably a good idea to link a sample. So other peoples can reproduce the bug

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Answer (score 0):

Open the file in binary file, i.e. `open(path_to_file, 'rb')`