# Getting error while installing sklearn | python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully

Tags: python, scikit-learn, charmap

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E4BkV.png)Collecting sklearn
Using cached sklearn-0.0.post4.tar.gz (3.6 kB)
Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [8 lines of output]
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
File "C:\Users\kusha\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-mtbck747\sklearn_33137b31d9da4e98b4212dacff7ddab4\setup.py", line 10, in <module>
LONG_DESCRIPTION = f.read()
File "C:\Program Files\Python310\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x8f in position 7: character maps to <undefined>
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

[notice] A new release of pip available: 22.3.1 -> 23.0.1
[notice] To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Tried to install SKlearn and getting this error while installing it. Can anyone help me with this

Comment: To update, run: python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip

Comment: Does this answer your question? [UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte X in position Y: character maps to <undefined>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9233027/unicodedecodeerror-charmap-codec-cant-decode-byte-x-in-position-y-character)

Answer (score 27):

use

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

instead of

```
pip install sklearn
```