UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90
So, yesterday I was having issues trying to define all columna via the data frame's to_sql method. For the most part, this works just fine.
One file I was trying to process, however, is giving me an odd error. See below.
When I run this :
 data.to_sql
    (
        name=f'tbl{table_name}'
        , schema='stage'
        , con=odbc_ntt.con
        , if_exists='replace'
        , index=False, dtype=sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR(length=2000)
    )

I get error:
 UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: character maps to <undefined>  

When I run this, it runs just fine.
data.to_sql
    (
        name=f'tbl{table_name}'
        , schema='stage'
        , con=odbc_ntt.con
        , if_exists='replace'
        , index=False, dtype=sqlalchemy.types.NVARCHAR
    )    

stack trace:
python -m trace --trace 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 194, in _run_module_as_main
    return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\trace.py", line 755, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\trace.py", line 735, in main
    code = compile(fp.read(), opts.progname, 'exec')
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 2: character maps to <undefined> 

Now, I did check the file for using characters or otherwise bad actors. These did not exist in the source file. I tried enforcing Utf-8 encoding, nothing.
I'm kind of at a loss here because the obvious things aren't sticking. Any assistance appreciated.

I guess no one knows whats up? I have tried so many things and nothing is happening. :'(

Possibly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/9233027/2144390

@gordThompson I actually found myself on that very page. The problem does not exist when I do not define a length of the nvarchar. Seems comical to me. I have tried dynamically creating the definition dict as well, and still the same result.

"I did check the file for using characters or otherwise bad actors" - So you are reading a text(?) file into a DataFrame? Can you isolate a row in the DF that triggers the error?

@gordthompson I am in fact reading a csv into a dataframe. the hex value 0x90 shows un in a lot of rows, starting at the second one. Notepad++ shows is as NUL. I have tried various different ways to try and remove it or encode it a particular way. No matter what I do the stack trace I provided is the underlying error. For some reason python still wants to encode it as cp1252. Iv tried opening it and encoding it and then passing it to to_sql, same thing. Kind of at a loss.

The thing thats the most confusing is f I remove the length param from the dtype, this error goes away. :|

Did you try pd.read_csv(…, encoding="latin1") ?

@gordthompson among many other encdoings, yes sir i have.

You might try adding a PYTHONIOENCODING=latin1 environment variable.
