# Recursive directory find files replace string using fileInput module. How?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, recursion, directory

I am creating a simple python script to find and replace strings inside of files which are also inside of sub-folders and so on. This calls for recursion.

The following script finds and replaces a string for another string found in every file inside of every folder of the target parent folder.

I've found this post on here suggesting the use of `fileinput` module in order to avoid reading entire files into memory which could slow things down...

[...simplify the text replacement in a file without requiring to read the whole file in memory...](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25885751/687137)

[Credits @jfs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/jfs)

Python is very dynamic and honestly, I get lost on the many different ways to accomplish the same task.

How can I integrate this approach into my script below?

```
import subprocess, os, fnmatch

if os.name == 'nt':
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("cls", shell=True)
        return
else:
    def clear_console():
        subprocess.call("clear", shell=True)
        return

# Globals
menuChoice = 0
searchCounter = 0

# Recursive find/replace with file extension argument.
def findReplace(directory, find, replace, fileExtension):

    global searchCounter

    #For all paths, sub-directories & files in (directory)...
    for path, dirs, files in os.walk(os.path.abspath(directory)):
        #For each file found with (FileExtension)...
        for filename in fnmatch.filter(files, fileExtension):
            #Construct the target file path...
            filepath = os.path.join(path, filename)
            #Open file correspondent to target filepath.
            with open(filepath) as f:
                # Read it into memory.
                s = f.read()
            # Find and replace all occurrances of (find).
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            # Write these new changes to the target file path.
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
                # increment search counter by one.
                searchCounter += 1

    # Report final status.
    print ('  Files Searched: ' + str(searchCounter))
    print ('')
    print ('  Search Status : Complete')
    print ('')
    input ('  Press any key to exit...')

def mainMenu():
    global menuChoice
    global searchCounter

    # range lowest index is 1 so range of 6 is 1 through 7.
    while int(menuChoice) not in range(1,1):

        clear_console()
        print ('')
        print ('  frx v1.0 - Menu')
        print ('')
        print ('  A. Select target file type extension.')
        print ('  B. Enter target directory name. eg -> target_directory/target_subfolder')
        print ('  C. Enter string to Find.')
        print ('  D. Enter string to Replace.')
        print ('')
        print ('  Menu')
        print ('')

        menuChoice = input('''
      1. All TXT  files. (*.txt )

      Enter Option: ''')
        print ('')

        # Format as int
        menuChoice = int(menuChoice)

        if menuChoice == 1:

            fextension = '*.txt'

            # Set directory name
            tdirectory = input('  Target directory name? ')
            tdirectory = str(tdirectory)
            print ('')

            # Set string to Find
            fstring = input('  String to find? (Ctrl + V) ')
            fstring = str(fstring)
            print ('')

            # Set string to Replace With
            rstring = input('  Replace with string? (Ctrl + V) ')
            rstring = str(rstring)
            print ('')

            # Report initial status
            print ('  Searching for occurrences of ' + fstring)
            print ('  Please wait...')
            print ('')

            # Call findReplace function
            findReplace('./' + tdirectory, fstring, rstring, fextension)

# Initialize program
mainMenu()

# Action Sample...
#findReplace("in this dir", "find string 1", "replace with string 2", "of this file extension")

# Confirm.
#print("done.")
```

Comment: I would guess to do the `for line in FileInput(files, inplace=True):line.replace(text, replacement)` part, and for `files` use `fnmatch.filter(files, fileExtension)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your check that the inputs are '.txt' files is good; it relieves you of needing to worry about passing 'rb' or 'wb' to `open()`.

You say you don't want to allocate N bytes for an N-byte file, for fear that occasionally N may be quite large. Better to limit the memory allocation to size of longest text line rather than size of biggest file. Let's break out a helper function. Delete / replace these lines:

```
            #Open file correspondent to target filepath.
            with open(filepath) as f:
                # Read it into memory.
                s = f.read()
            # Find and replace all occurrances of (find).
            s = s.replace(find, replace)
            # Write these new changes to the target file path.
            with open(filepath, "w") as f:
                f.write(s)
                # increment search counter by one.
                searchCounter += 1
```

with a call to the helper function and then a bump of the counter:

```
            update(filepath, find, replace)
            searchCounter += 1
```

and then define the helper:

```
def update(filepath, find, replace, temp_fspec='temp'):
    assert temp_fspec != filepath, filepath
    with open(filepath) as fin:
        with open(temp_fspec) as fout:
            for line in fin:
                fout.write(line.replace(find, replace))
    os.rename(temp_fspec, filepath)  # overwrites filepath
```

Using `fileinput` is not relevant, since that would catenate lines from many inputs into a single output stream, and your requirement is to associate each output with its own input. The `for line in` idiom is what matters here, and it works the same in `fileinput` as in the suggested `update()` helper.

Consider putting unusual characters in temp_fspec to reduce the chance of collision, or perhaps make it a fully qualified path in the same filesystem but above the affected subtree so it's guaranteed to never collide.

This version should typically take a little longer to run, especially for lengthy files full of short lines. Maximum memory footprint for this version should be much smaller, if max file size >> max line length. If very long lines are a concern, then a binary chunking approach would be more appropriate, finessing the case where `find` might span a chunk boundary. We needn't handle that case in the current code if we assume that `find` does not contain `'\n'` newlines.

We can simplify two versions of your clear screen routine down to one by phrasing it this way:

```
def clear_console():
    clear = 'cls' if os.name == 'nt' else 'clear'
    subprocess.call(clear, shell=True)
    return
```